# Highlighting questions in which I have already posted or commented

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, information-display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make recent activity and responses show new comments on questions/answers I have commented on (even if I don’t own them)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have)

**This is not exact duplicate**

> That page talks about recent activity, I was suggesting a tick mark in the global questions' list as seen in this image (screen shot from actionscript.org). The tick mark on the left side tells me that I've posted in that thread.

[alt text http://lh3.ggpht.com/_dMvpiHJOOxw/StatrtHusqI/AAAAAAAAATg/hYU4jn3hGe4/ASdotOrg.jpg](http://lh3.ggpht.com/_dMvpiHJOOxw/StatrtHusqI/AAAAAAAAATg/hYU4jn3hGe4/ASdotOrg.jpg)

Is there a way to identify the questions that I've posted to or commented to in the various `Questions` tab?

If not, I think it would be nice to have a tick mark near those questions in which I have asked/answered/commented in the main page and the various `Questions` pages. Currently, hot/active tabs only shows the name of the user who updated the question recently. If there is a tick mark near questions with my posts, it would be like saying **"Hey you've made a post here, why don't you go back and check what OP/others are doing in there?"**. Basically, I've seen this in many vBulletin based forums and am so used to it that I'd like to see it here too.

Also, currently there is no way(?) to track the questions that I've commented (and not posted). Many a times, we seek some clarification from OP in a comment (which I believe is more appropriate than posting it as answer) and forget to come back. Now, given the traffic in SO, someone will take it from there, but still I believe there should be some way for me to keep track of those commented posts. As of now, I'm favoriting such questions and removing favorite star once it's no more required.

Comment: Duplicate talks about the same functionality that you're looking for. The only difference is that you're looking for it to apply on the questions page. The other request is keeping track, not on the questions page, but on your own activity page.