# See at a glance whether I've interacted with a question?

Tags: feature-request, questions, unanswered-questions, views

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Highlighting questions in which I have already posted or commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25857/highlighting-questions-in-which-i-have-already-posted-or-commented)

It would be really nice to be able to tell at a glance -- ideally from the main page -- whether I've already answered a question. It would also be great to see other things -- whether I've commented on it, etc. Just a thought!

Comment: Do you plan to answer **all** the Questions?

Comment: @pavium, why not? But seriously I just think it might be nice to have some indication at least that I've commented/voted/contributed an answer, etc., that I can at least see at a glance, even if the list of unanswered questions doesn't really make sense for all the sites

Comment: I can see why it wouldn't make sense on SO, but even on the smaller sites, can you come up with answers for **all** questions? I know *I* couldn't, and I wouldn't even try.

Comment: @pavium, a pretty good point -- I will reformulate. Just a moment.

Comment: @pavium, am now requesting something slightly different and perhaps more useful everywhere.

Comment: Don't clear your browsers cache.

Comment: @jcolebrand so this is implemented?

Comment: @Joe, say what? I meant, your browser will remember the stuff you've seen.

Comment: @jcolebrand, I think I'm just being dense. I understand my browser knows the history -- but it can only indicate whether or not I've been somewhere right? It doesn't know I've answered/commented/whatever. Very good point though that it *will visually discriminate* based on whether I've interacted with the question.

Comment: This may not make sense on SO, or even the smaller sites, but it makes perfect sense within a tag.

Comment: I thought that's what you wanted

Comment: @jcolebrand, I'd like something a bit more detailed -- some kind of indication that I've commented/voted/contributed an answer...

Comment: Yeah, originally it was a joke. It's gone on a bit too long now.