# Find my own answers to a question - flag threads I have posts in

Tags: feature-request, search, user-interface

When a thread pops back upto the front page that I'm sure I provided an answer to - could there by some visual highlighting? Then I can check to see if somebody voted up/down or provided a better answer.

Especially if it's a multiple page wiki type thread it's hard to find your own answer. Some way of searching for or jumping straight to your own answer would be good.

Looking in your own user page doesn't really help, I have >10 pages of answers and I can only order them by score.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the dupe - I couldn't find it.

Comment: Arggh - when I changed my title the dupe popped up as the first suggestion!

Comment: This question is being posited as the duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have - but I'm not sure it is an exact match