# How can I get notified (by email or RSS) of the stuff I'm involved in at stack overflow?

Tags: feature-request, feed, email, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make recent activity and responses show new comments on questions/answers I have commented on (even if I don’t own them)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have)

I'd like to be notified by RSS or email (if by email then right away, not once a day) of:

- comments and answers on questions I've started
- comments on answers I've commented on

Is there a way to do this?  I find myself hitting refresh and browsing to StackOverflow to see if people have responded to comments I've left etc.  Hopefully SO has a feature so I don't ever have to actually check stuff on SO, instead just get notified when something happened so I can respond!

Comment: Upvote here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have

Comment: Thx, upvoted!!!

Comment: I didn't understand the "exact duplicate". The link points to a question about the web interface. This question is about email or RSS. The other question is marked as request-status-completed and I still see no email or RSS notification! :(

Comment: I agree the with @Cawas the so called duplicate has very little in common with the original.  The "duplicate" is about wanting website notifications for comments that come after.  The accepted answer being that the notification be given on the website when the @ notation is used.  It says nothing about email or rss notification (even when the @ notation is used.)  It also mentions nothing at all about the first bullet point here.

Comment: +1 for RSS feed for all the activity which appears in inbox