# Is there a RSS to the 'Stack Exchange Inbox'? How about to Activity?

Tags: support, feed, global-inbox

Just wondering if I'm missing something here. Also, I couldn't find any previous question related to this.

Comment: +1 Yes, I want inbox RSS!

Answer (score 36):

#### An RSS feed for your global inbox is finally here!

I have put a lot of effort into making this process as smooth as possible. Here are the steps you need to take to create your custom RSS feed:

1. Head on over to my website and register for an account:

   http://quickmediasolutions.com/accounts/register

   (Registration is free and you also get some other nice features too like a custom OpenID.)
2. Once you have logged in to your new account, head on over to [Stack Exchange Dashboard](https://quickmediasolutions.com/stackexchange/) and click the "Stack Exchange" tab:

   [image]
3. Ensure that "Read Inbox" is checked and click the "Authorize" button. You will then be presented with the Stack Exchange authorization page.

   [image]
4. Once the process is complete, head back to [this page](http://quickmediasolutions.com/stackexchange) and you should see your inbox RSS feed URL:

   [image]

A few things to note here:

- Data is cached for up to 10 minutes to reduce load on my site. After a few days I may lower this value if things are running well.
- This feed is *your custom feed*. Anyone / anything you share the URL with will have access to your inbox, so be careful where you share it.
- If you ever change your mind, just visit [this page](http://quickmediasolutions.com/accounts/profile/stackexchange) and click the "Deauthorize" button:

  [image]

  Your access token will be invalidated and your API data destroyed.
- If you are worried about your personal information, we [have a privacy policy](http://quickmediasolutions.com/privacy).
- Feedback is appreciated!

Comment: crazy George attacking again! :P

Comment: Does this work with ServerFault too?

Comment: @BullShark: Absolutely!

Comment: Would it be possible to add a feed with all my activity? Like http://*.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/me combined.

Comment: @Michel: Unfortunately, no. You might want to take a look at Stack2RSS for something like that.

Comment: @NathanOsman: Stack2RSS can't combine sites can it?

Comment: @uɐɯsOuɐɥʇɐN I couldn't reach http://quickmediasolutions.com/accounts/register any more. Is this still active? If not what are the alternatives?

Comment: @KhurshidAlam there were some brief technical issues - the site's back up now. Sorry about that. (Note: the screenshots above are out-of-date but the RSS feed is still there.)

Comment: Is this still active and relevant?

Comment: @shadow yes and yes.

Comment: Thanks, I closed a new question as duplicate of this one, and was worried it's not relevant after all those years.

Comment: This is down right now

Comment: @AndrewMacFie what error are you getting specifically? It's working fine on my end.

Comment: whoops, looks like a local firefox issue, weird

Comment: Is it possible to get a feed of only unseen inbox items?

Comment: Thanks for this. 2 feature requests. Could you add to the items in a feed which site they are from? And then would it be possibly, as an option, to also get reputation point changes in the notification list?

Answer (score 7):

This could easily be done... the contents of the inbox can be fetched with JSON using:

> `http://` **{SE Site Domain}** `/inbox/genuwine`

It would be trivial to write something that converted this to an RSS feed.

**However:**

- The above URL only works if you're logged in (technically it works if you send the login cookie to that URL).
- Based on that fact, the only thing that would be capable of creating and reading such a feed would be a UserScript or browser extension.

Comment: Sup George? Did you notice I've kinda abandoned Stack2RSS? :P Anyway, maybe someone who are willing to put up the effort on doing this, can use [Newt](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40927/how-do-you-do-to-keep-track-of-notifications/87528#87528) as a base - which already works in a quite similar fashion... While I'm glad with it and don't care that much about the RSS anymore, I'll wait and only accept an actual solution for it (or an authoritative answer on why this can't / shouldn't be done), rather than good pointers! ;)

Comment: @Cawas: No problem. I'd certainly like to hope that it could be done... though I really am not quite sure how.

Comment: Or: simply use the "[user responses feed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/142114/responses)", also linked in the bottom right corner of the "responses" tab on one's own profile.

Comment: @Arjan: Good find! I never noticed that.

Comment: Wait... a +25 bounty? awarded by Community?

Comment: Yup, @gobernador, if the bounty placer does not act, then Community may award half the value; see [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: Why "genuwine"? Is it a misspelling? Or is it meant to be? It seems to give valid JSON.

Comment: @Arjan It looks like the link in the bottom right corner of the *responses* tab is no longer available. However, going directly to `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/{user_id}/responses` works. Any idea why the link is missing?

Comment: Yes, @Piotr, unfortunately that is by design: [One's own profile no longer shows RSS feed for responses?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118242/ones-own-profile-no-longer-shows-rss-feed-for-responses)

Answer (score 5):

I haven't been able to find a **native** way of doing this for stackexchange, and [George Edison's original](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93615/138432) for individual stack exchange sites no longer works, so here is the equivalent today:

- *`http://`stack exchange site`/feeds/user/`user id`/responses`*
- *`http://`stack exchange site`/feeds/user/`user id*

Nor can I find an equivalent for Stack Exchange, and guessing the following URL simply doesn't work:

- *`http://stackexchange.com/feeds/user/`user id*

If you don't mind a **non-native** solution (by granting an external site access to your inbox), then obviously [George Edison's more recent solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135045/138432) will be good for you.

I have also posted another question *[What other hidden or inobvious RSS feeds are available on stackexchange and stack exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151519/138432)* here, to see if there are any other feeds available.

Comment: Doesn't [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135045/142114) work?

Comment: @GeorgeEdison - I've updated my answer to make it clear that I was referring to **native** solutions. I'm sure your new solution works perfectly, but it might not be for everyone. Thanks for the feedback though.