# Increasing number of frequency options for emailing unread inbox messages?

Tags: feature-request, comments, email, email-notification

In the profile preferences, it would be nice to have more option in terms of the frequency of "Email me my unread inbox messages".

Currently, the shorter possible time window is 3 hours. Personally, I would like to set it as short as possible.

Sometimes one gets really impatient about a question, or one benefits from a nice interaction with a responder who remains online for some time. Refreshing the page say every minute to see if something new came up is obviously not the most efficient way to deal with these situations. An email notification would be much more handy.

**Question** : Do you see any reason why such additional (shorter) settings could cause problems? Would that be too resource demanding for stack exchange servers?

Personally, I see at least one downside : **it could facilitate the use of comments as chatting device**, which is something stackechange tries to discourage.

Comment: You can also set up an RSS feed and use your favorite feed reading interface: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85897/is-there-a-rss-to-the-stack-exchange-inbox-how-about-to-activity

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to refresh the page repeatedly; with the magic of WebSockets, notifications will automatically display on your screen as they appear. (If this doesn't work for you, you're probably using an old or outdated browser; consider upgrading your browser or using a more modern one instead.)

Also, you could download the [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin) or [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange/id871299723) app for push notifications to your phone.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I would still prefer email notifications but these are usefull substitutes.