# RSS for my achievements and global inbox

Tags: feature-request, global-inbox, feed, achievements-dialog

I am sure a lot of users are visiting Stack Overflow regularly (and all of the sites from the Stack Exchange Network) to check whether a new comment/post/answer is posted as well as if there is a new upvote/achievement/etc.

Which is why I am proposing a **built-in RSS generator** to be implemented.

I am aware there are some third-party solutions (such as [Is there a RSS to the 'Stack Exchange Inbox'? How about to Activity?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85897/is-there-a-rss-to-the-stack-exchange-inbox-how-about-to-activity/135045#135045)) but my suggestion is this be implemented within the Stack Exchange system.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't one. However, you can use the StackExchange API's [read inbox](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox) method to access it, and create a RSS feed for the browser. One example will be something like [this](http://teamfreehugs.github.io/stackexchange/inboxreader/nice.html), or its [stackapps](https://stackapps.com/) [post](https://stackapps.com/questions/6475/inbox-reader-reads-your-inbox).

<sub>In fact, I'm going to make one now just for this</sub>