# How can I award the bounty to someone who only posted a comment?

Tags: support, bounties

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013936/difficualty-getting-flup-fcgi-script-to-work/). Even though Tobu did not answer my question, he helped me find the answer. How can I award him the bounty?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could ask him to re-post his response as an answer, so that it can be upvoted and accepted.

<strike>However, he may not see the message ([commenters do not receive notification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have) when someone has replied to their comment), so you could try getting his attention by replying to another one of his posts (and deleting that comment when he has seen it).</strike>  [Comment replies now have a notification system.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/)

Comment: alternately if this user has contact info in their user profile, you could use that.

Comment: Please update this.

Comment: @Tshepang: update how?

Comment: I think this was written when comment notifications weren't implemented.

Answer (score 0):

There definitely should be a way to either reward a comment or promote a comment to an answer. For my question, the person who added the comment which directly led to the answer didn't come back in time to write up it as an answer.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and is a comment at best. Either find an feature request that asks to implement this, so you can support that FR with upvotes or if none yet exists, create a new feature request.

Comment: You are right of course, first time on meta so thought it was more of a discussion format.

Comment: Welcome on meta then ;) ... we do have discussions but still in the Q/A format. Yes, that hurts now and then ... see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99247/is-the-qa-format-of-metas-suitable-for-discussion