# Is the Q&A format of metas suitable for discussion?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, per-site-meta

IIRC, SE emphasizes the fact that QA format of SE sites are designed to discourage discussion. But sometimes on meta we need to discuss issues, they can be lengthly and can go back-and-forth and that is normal. The QA format forces people to adopt to the QA format which is not natural, for example someone raises a point about an answer in another answer and the first one answers in another answer and all end up as answers to the original post without any threading. In serious discussions this makes it difficult to follow the discussion.

I think a format supporting something like [Robert's rules of order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert%27s_Rules_of_Order) would make more sense and will be more useful than the QA format for these meta discussions. It would be nice if there was a checkbox like community wiki checkbox that could be set for a discussion question on meta to change the QA format to a format more suitable for a discussion.

Comment: Do you have any particular examples of where this has become a problem? Or is this merely theoretical?

Comment: @CodyGray: I have examples of the situation I have described, but I am not sure I understand what you mean by "become a problem". The format causes difficulty in following discussions, and it is clear that the current QA format is not designed for users to answer to answers of other users, which is common in such discussions.

Comment: Feel free to share those examples, then... I'm talking about concrete instances here on Meta where the format has hindered discussion. Sure, it *sounds* like the Q&A format would be a bad fit for the Meta sites; that's what I first thought, too. But after hanging out for a while and participating for a while longer, I've come to see that it works quite nicely. So *theoretically* this is a problem, but in *reality*, I don't think it is.

Comment: @CodyGray: [search for question with say 20 answer here and sort them by votes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=answers%3a20) and you will find plenty of situations I have described, in particular when there are strong opinion for and against something it becomes quite difficult to follow the discussion. Here is an example of the situation I have described: [1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-the-noobs)