# Facebook-Style comment notification - implemented or not?

Tags: support

Forgive me that I'm almost certainly producing a duplicate with this, but I'm confused.

In [**this question**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have), the OP makes a feature request for "Facebook style" comment notification - i.e. when you make a comment somewhere, you get notified of all subsequent comments, no matter whether you are personally targeted using `@username` or not. The question is marked `status-completed` as of January 16 **this year**.

However, the notification system as it works right now, does *not* notify you of subsequent comments, which is kind of annoying because in the normal flow of the conversation, you tend to forget to address the user.

Has this changed since that question was tagged `status-completed`?

Comment: You have to remember the @ every time.  But, jeff considers this complete.

Comment: I think it'd also be handy for a list of "relevant" usernames to popup when you start typing `@` like facebook does, but that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

The question you reference asks for all your comments to be on [your activity page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187606?tab=activity#tab-top), and, indeed, they are.

It also asks for all comments on questions you've commented on to be on [your responses page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/187606?startdate=2010-02-16%2013%3a45%3a40z&enddate=2010-02-16%2023%3a59%3a59z&tab=responses#tab-top), and they are not.

Per [Jeff's answer on that question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have/35913#35913), they didn't implement exactly what Kip asked for. The question didn't mention "@" notification at all, but that's what they did.