# Email notification about comments

Tags: feature-request, email, notifications

Somebody asks question, I reply, they post comment on my reply. I don't get notification about their comment. Is that normal or is it bug?

Answer (score 3):

SO doesn't send email notifications for comments, period.  You will have the notification icon (next to your name in the banner) light up if they comment on your question/answer or respond to a comment you made using your name in the "Twitter-style", @Rubycut.

Answer (score 1):

As for E-Mail notification: That doesn't exist on SO (except for the negligeable daily thingie).

As for notifications not even turning up in the envelope: Sadly, that's by design. If it's not your question or answer the comment is made in, it will take a `@Rubycut` for the message to reach you.

[Related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have)