# Prevent (or at least notify about) display names shorter than 3 chars

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications, comment-replies, display-names

Until yesterday my display name was 2 characters. This ended when I started wondering about some issues with comments and notifications, went to meta, and found out that

> there is an [important feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have/35913#35913) which only works if the display name is at least three character long.

Methinks, I should not have discovered this accidentally. I should have been warned, maybe even prevented from creating a display name that turns off some of the site's features. Kindly consider implementing this.

Comment: ... That's a long username you have

Comment: Oh, great - i was wondering what comment notifications others referred to sometimes ;)

Comment: I'm not sure it is allowed to enter an actual serious feature-request on this day.

Comment: @dmckee but, this question is dated April 2nd! Surely it's allowed then!

Answer (score 5):

We no longer allow names of 2 characters.

3 characters is the minimum name length, and this is enforced.

<s>However, users who have an *existing* 2 character name may retain it, but will be unable to copy their profile from site to site until they make their username at least 3 characters.</s>

Update: as of 14 September 2011, previously existing shorter display names [have been padded with dots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106200/why-was-a-period-added-to-my-short-display-name/106213#106213).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, very true..One should be warned when he/she entered a user name with 2 or 1 character. But to restrict the length of user name is not at all necessary. Warning feature should be there.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's perfectly reasonable. And we don't want a username of `A` on here. Every other website in the world has minimum lengths on usernames, so why not SO?

Comment: because, as somebody who previously went by a two letter name (Back on IRC, a shorter name left more room for text!) very few sites allowed this, for no good reason - same with arbitrary password restrictions (No more than 12 characters? Why? You're hashing it, right?), wheras the trilogy, which DOES have a good reason (notifications) doesn't - I don't see why this should change. A warning would be good, though.