# Three character minimum display name on Stackapps?

Tags: discussion, stackapps

I just created my account on stackapps.

When I tried to copy my profile from my associated accounts, it blew up ("something bad happened").

So I tried to fill in the information manually, and I discovered that there is a 3-character minimum on display name (which is, I assume, the reason the copy failed).

I've had my SO/MSO/SF/SU display name as **TM** for a very long time...

Is this 3-char limit only for stackapps, or am I just grandfathered in on the other sites?

If I change my display name one day on SO/MSO/SF/SU, will I be unable to go back?

Comment: Wait when did this 3 char limit come in effect!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See:

[Prevent (or at least notify about) display names shorter than 3 chars](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45241/prevent-or-at-least-notify-about-display-names-shorter-than-3-chars/50693#50693)

> We no longer allow names of 2 characters.
>
> 3 characters is the minimum name length, and this is enforced.
>
> However, users who have an existing 2 character name may retain it, but will be unable to copy their profile from site to site until they make their username at least 3 characters.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you were grandfathered in, and thus any future changes will be subject to a 3-character limit.