# Why was a period added to my short display name?

Tags: support, display-names

I originally had "yx" as display name (when Stack Overflow still allowed 2 character display names). I did not change it, but I now see [my display name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38264/yx) contains a dot.  Why was this change made?

Even [Jeff said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50724/three-character-minimum-display-name-on-stackapps/50742#50742) I could retain it; yet, somehow it was changed without my knowledge.

Comment: Perhaps its a particular time of the month?

Comment: I don't see any record of a name change in your history, so I'm guessing it was done automatically.  Maybe when you associated accounts?

Comment: I noticed that [`TM`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/131073/tm) (the guy who posted that question you linked) also has a period added to his name.  Looks like a policy change?

Comment: Most likely the grace period is over and there was job to make all display names three characters at least, filling the gaps with dots.

Comment: It appears that this has been done to [everyone with short names as well](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/112584/) regardless of recent activity.

Comment: @Rosinante Yes, but if it's XY it can't have a '.'  (That's an XY chromosome joke, BTW).

Comment: I want my user name to include descriptions of violent acts upon people who include tags in their titles, laced liberally with curse words such as "F" and "S" and "MF."  Unfortunately, I can't have that either.

Comment: I want a period _and_ a unicorn in my user name

Comment: @belisarius: you could rename yourself to `belisarius.廌`. At least according to the Unicode database [that's valid](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/5ecc/index.htm).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's been [over a year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50724/three-character-minimum-display-name-on-stackapps/50742#50742) since we had that grandfather period; users have had plenty of time to adjust.

We're now normalizing all display names to be a minimum of 3 characters, so we don't have to keep special cases in our code.

Comment: nooo, I'm no longer a special case :P

Comment: Give those poor souls a "Grandfather" badge, so that they feel special again ;-)

Comment: do I win a prize for doing this myself?