# Bug when linking accounts with other sites

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, association, display-names

I got a bug when logging in for the first time on appstack and trying to associate my account with my other accounts on the trilogy site. I am using Google Open ID; then I say 'OK' on the Google page to access my credentials; then I am back on the appstack page and I click 'Create Account' and that causes an error ('This is our fault... bla bla').

So I click the login again, Google Open ID again and that logs me in directly. So clearly part of the user creation process worked. However, I did get 'user1021' instead of my normal name shown at the top of my page.

So I came here to post the bug, but I had never registered for this site either, so I go through the same process of account creation and lo-and-behold, I experience the exact same issue! (I get user name 'user147381' this time).

So it looks like a reproductible bug and I even think I know the cause. On StackOverflow, my username is 'AD', 2-letter, that's it. When I try to edit my profile on AppStack, I get an error message when I put in 'AD': 'Display name must be at least 3 characters'.

That's it... I sure hope I can keep my 'AD' name on StackOverflow!

Edit: I can replicate the buggy behavior at will with the 'Copy my profile from StackOverflow' button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new rule was implemented which requires at least 3 letters in the username. See [Jeff's post here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45241/prevent-or-at-least-notify-about-display-names-shorter-than-3-chars/50693#50693).

The most relevant quote is the following:

> However, users who have an existing 2 character name may retain it, but will be unable to copy their profile from site to site until they make their username at least 3 characters.

The error in account creation is probably a result of the automatic account association that was also recently implemented. Since that automatically attempts to copy the profile, it would identically cause an error.

Comment: Yes, this all makes sense. However, there should be a clear error message instead of the unknown error page.