# Notifications for comments of others posts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make recent activity and responses show new comments on questions/answers I have commented on (even if I don't own them)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have)

The scenario is

I commented on the post of X. and then X comment back. But i didn't receive any notification. Shouldn't i receive notification through envelop??

This is the post i am talking about. 
[Setting z-index on draggable elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217311/setting-z-index-on-draggable-elements/5217511#5217511)

Now This is not my post. I commented something. and he commented back. but didn't receive any notification. I have to manually lookup every time whether he commented or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look again. Are you sure that Hussein answered *you*?

It *seems* like he did, given the context, but there's no way for the code to be sure, because he didn't @mahesh you. In fact noone @ed anyone in that comment stream. *He* gets notified because you're commenting on his answer, but if he doesn't @ you, there's no way for the system to know that it is you who should be notified.

Comment: Okay. I am telling that "If I am a part of a comment in post then i should be notified any events, but however if anyone explicitly specifies @someone then only @someone should be notified". I know this works as designed but i am talking about extending it.

Comment: OK, I didn't catch that. Good luck, I doubt it will happen though.

Comment: Hm..... Now i think it is sort of a bug too. because "it is obvious that when the author, comment on his own post which is commented by 'someone' he meant the message pass to 'someone'."

Comment: @mahesh, ok, but let's say 10 people have commented on a post, then the author answers one of them, (without @): do all the others really want to be notified?

Comment: I Definitely Agree. If there 2 people '@' is definitely required. but what about **only one user**. i didn't received any notification for  your first comment. isn't that a bug? now it is so much obvious that you are talking to me and only me.

Comment: @mahesh, no, the bug is me forgetting the @ on my first comment, though I admit that is very ironic.

Comment: i disagree a bit on that. because programs are made to make life and thinking easier not to make them strict and follow the rules. whatever, my question is closed and there is no much doing in that. as you are the only one sounded on the board marking your answer as correct ;)

Comment: @mahesh, what you are suggesting is a micro-refinement, which probably wouldn't get implemented. But it wasn't immediately obvious from your question exactly what you wanted, which is why it got closed. You *could* try asking a new - more precise - question. As I understand it, you are suggesting that *if* a user comments on their own post *and* there is only one person who has previously commented, *then* that person should be notified.

Comment: yep. thanks for suggesting the idea. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82134/micro-refinement-to-notifications-for-comments-of-others-posts