# Micro-refinement to notifications for comments of others posts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comment-replies

If a user comments on their own post and there is only one person who has previously commented, then that person should be notified when the author comments even if '@user' is not specified

courtesy to Benjol from my closed question [Notifications for comments of others posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82126/notifications-for-comments-of-others-posts/82129#82129)

Comment: +1 because I *forgot* the @ on my answer to that question :)

Comment: +1, I've seen several cases where this would have been helpful for new users who didn't know the "@" syntax.

Comment: Or maybe just add a default `@user` to the new comment, so that you can delete it if it is not appropriate.

Comment: How about a 'reply-to' link on comments? Not for threaded discussion, but just so that by clicking the 'reply-to' link the comment field is pre-populated with the appropriate `@user` syntax?

Comment: @David, already exists as a user script: http://stackapps.com/questions/2051/reply-links-on-comments

Comment: +1 Very nice.  I *often* comment to new users that don't know the '@user' syntax, and I've already gotten a few replies from this.

Comment: This cuts both way. Now it's even more confusing when an `@`-reply is needed and when it isn't. I am not thrilled with htis.

Comment: Wait, this means that by default I don't get notified about new comments on a post that I have commented on? I probably missed a lot of things because of that!

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82237/1138813

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Excellent idea - this will be pushed tonight.

Comment: Wow, just got my first notification! I told @mahesh "Good luck, I doubt it will happen though.", I take it all back!

Comment: I *loves* it! This solves a lot of problems very nicely.