# Is there a new comment notification system?

Tags: discussion, comments, notifications, comment-replies

It looks like I'm being notified of comments to questions/answers I commented on, without the replies actually containing "@Matt" or similar.

I couldn't find any recent Q&As on this behavior. Is it new? (I like it.)

Comment: For the future, consider checking out our [maintained changelog](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) when something weird comes up. It's fairly well maintained and will contain a lot of these larger changes. No harm in having the question, I say, but having the answer available is a useful tool.

Comment: Ah yes, time to favorite that link. Thanks! Remind me to accept your answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: Nice demonstration of the new system, haha. ♪ I'll be sure to do the same to you in 10 minutes, then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was implemented as [per here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82134/micro-refinement-to-notifications-for-comments-of-others-posts). If you are the only other commenter on a post, comments from the post author will trigger a notification to you even if they forget to use the @ syntax.

I actually got two notifications this morning. It's a very nice feature.

Comment: Dangit. I searched for "comment notification" and that doesn't show up on the first page by [relevance](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=comment%20notification) or [newest](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=comment%20notification).

Comment: It's 13, but that should be sufficient, aye? ♪