# Don't remove the @ part of my comment

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, comment-replies, automatic-edits

Recently I posted a comment on Stack Overflow on an answer by (say) Felix. He replied to the comment, and when replying to him I started my comment with "@Felix". Stack Overflow stripped that part of my comment out.

The engine should leave that in place, even if I'm redundantly specifying the person attached to the answer. Sometimes, regrettably and hopefully temporarily, discussion ensues and so it's useful to see to whom a comment is directed. It's inappropriate for the engine to remove an explicitly-typed direction in this way. Without wanting to blow one's own horn, the engine isn't smarter *(in most cases)* than the person typing the comment, and should leave it alone, complete with the "@xyz" part at the outset if explicitly typed.

Note that this is **not** a duplicate of ["Eeeeek - what happened to my @ salutation?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation). That is asking *why*. I'm not asking why. I'm saying it's wrong and should be fixed.

---

See also: [*Tell the user who will be notified of a comment*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99261/tell-the-user-who-will-be-notified-of-a-comment)

---

**Update 2011/07/21**: Having made my request and reasons clear, I had stepped back from this and just lurked, since I didn't really have anything more to add. But others did, and I got re-engaged, etc., etc. Since my original edit and update were a bit rambling, I'm replacing it with what I believe to be the main points in favor of and against keeping the change.

Separately, I realized that I'd failed to do the obvious thing and suggest an alternative, and so I've done that now: [*Tell the user who will be notified of a comment*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99261/tell-the-user-who-will-be-notified-of-a-comment).

Apologies in advance if anything has been lost in translation/condensation (feel free to fix it, just try not to be even more verbose than I am):

Arguments **in favor** of keeping the change:

1. `@postowner` is noisy. Protecting the signal-to-noise ratio is ***vital*** to keeping the standard high on the Stack Exchange network. [**(more)**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97283/dont-remove-the-part-of-my-comment/97290#97290) If you want to specifically address the postowner, just use `postowner` without the `@`, e.g. `joe:` or `Joe,`.
2. `@postowner` teaches new users that they have to do that to notify the postowner, and of course, they don't. Just commenting on a post always notifies the postowner.

Arguments **against** keeping the change itself:

1. `@postowner` is not noisy. `postowner` is no less noisy than `@postowner`. This does nothing to improve the signal-to-noise ratio.
2. `@postowner` is not just to notify the postowner, we use `@xyz` a lot like names on Stack Exchange sites and about 18 million other places online. The `@` convention didn't originate at Stack Overflow and isn't unique to the Stack Exchange network. To ignore this is to ignore the human factor.
3. Forcing their removal reduces clarity. Sometimes when you comment on a post, you're commenting to all readers; other times, you're commenting specifically to the post owner and so the natural thing is `@postowner` as with everywhere else we direct comments (on Stack Exchange and elsewhere). Their removal breaks the distinction, forcing workarounds.
4. Workarounds for the change cause more harm than making the change prevents. If users see a lot of `postowner:` or `@ postowner` (note the space) or `postowner,` they mistakenly learn the `@` is *generally* unnecessary and leave it out when they *do* need it, preventing the person they're trying to direct the comment to from being notified. This is active harm.
5. It's inappropriate for automated systems to silently edit content from actual intelligent beings, especially without a means of overriding that edit, without an overwhemlingly good reason, which this is far from being.
6. It's too intrusive, feels like censorship and editing for style, turning off new users who might otherwise contribute. One person's "noise" is another person's essential social lubricant.
7. It makes it harder to teach by example / is confusing for new users / is over-complicated (even for established users). [**(more)**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97283/dont-remove-the-part-of-my-comment/97907#97907) Sometimes you need the `@`, sometimes you're actively prevented from using it. [Quoting Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down/7183#7183):

   > When the answer to a problem is "let's make things arbitrarily more complicated", it is rarely the correct answer
8. It forces asymmetry if there is a degree of back-and-forth. [**(more & example)**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97283/dont-remove-the-part-of-my-comment/97907#97907)
9. Finally: In the face of overwhelming, unambiguous negative feedback, it would be simply inappropriate to keep the change *even if* the 90% expressing their disagreement with the change were wrong. [**(more)**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97283/dont-remove-the-part-of-my-comment/97969#97969) Its benefits are nowhere near sufficient to justify overruling that kind of majority, especially not given that [*"We don’t run Stack Overflow. The community does."*](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) Overriding the community *on this* is active harm.

Comment: #T.J. I say we should just use # for addressing the poster

Comment: Well done for trying and picking up the glove but as was the case with the envelope R.I.P (where many members wanted it restored) changing decision of the Developers once such a decision was made is impossible.

Comment: @Shadow, there have been instances in the past of declined posts turning into completed posts.

Comment: @Popular I doubt this one will become one of these.. the cases I saw are new ideas here we're talking about restoring previous behavior.

Comment: @Shadow, yeah, I'm not hopeful for this one either, but I thought it was worth pointing out since you used the word "impossible."

Comment: @Shadow, @Popular: The envelope thing was a botched enhancement and total UX failure *that was then corrected*. Correcting it makes up for everything. The system we have now is a good one; for a short time, we had something that was screwed up, but it didn't last.

Comment: Good point @T.J. but still my points stands and the problem is that Jeff consider every non vital word in question, answer or comment as "noise" and we can't really change the way he thinks.

Comment: @Shadow: True. But while in the early days what Jeff thought should almost certainly have been law -- that's how you establish something, with a clear vision and strong guidance -- three years later, if the claim is that "the community runs it," it's time to let the community do exactly that. This kind of micro-management can very well kill the SE network. It's grown beyond one man's vision, and it needs to. And again, **if** you're going to flaunt the community, *pick something worthwhile*. One `@` is not remotely worthwhile.

Comment: Thanks for bounty. I wonder if there's a way to re-open this now that Jeff is long gone?

Comment: And over 4 years after the implementation, it seems even SE developers are still confused. Like [“Comments should be at least 15 characters in length” does not make clear @name might be excluded](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264451/) shows that **a developer made the Android app automatically add the `@name` part [when replying to a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264454/dont-automatically-add-name-when-replying-to-ops-comment-in-the-android-app)**, after which the same thing is silently ignored when counting the comment length.

Answer (score 125):

This change also makes it harder to teach by example. When a new user enters a site, I make sure to reply to them in the form *"@newuser: What do you mean by X? Y or Z? `(Use @Jan in your reply and I get a notification)`"* This teaches them right from the start how the commenting system works. I know that you also get a notification without an @lert when no one else joined the conversation (yet), but this is an exception to the rule, for all those new users that don't know the system yet. We should not make the exception more prominent.

*"@postowner, you forgot to provide some information"* is also a pretty natural sentence, so it's not that noisy. I would not object to removing it from the global inbox notifications, but please leave it in them comments themselves.

Comment: the help link available under every [Add Comment] button already explains the basics of replies, without littering comments with thousands of noise words. Also FYI, we detect when only two people are talking and [notifications will work regardless](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82134/micro-refinement-to-notifications-for-comments-of-others-posts). Try it...

Comment: furthermore, what you describe actually "teaches" new users something incorrect -- that is, the post owner is *always* notified of every comment, and seeing other "experienced" users choose to type @postowner would imply otherwise.

Comment: @Jeff: notification and content are two completely different things. Please don't try to argue that one implies and restricts the other.

Comment: @Jeff, you're applying a technical solution to a social problem. At some point the newbie will need to learn the `@` protocol, and by introducing inconsistencies into the system you've made that much harder. As for teaching something incorrect - well it's only incorrect because you declared it so. You could easily change your mind.

Comment: @mark it isn't inconsistent; **the post owner is always notified of every comment on their post, forever, always, in every possible circumstance, no matter what the contents of that comment are.** The optional part is notifying *someone else* which is what @username is about.

Comment: @Jeff, it is inconsistent in that **sometimes you need it, sometimes you don't** and **sometimes it's deleted, sometimes it isn't**. It doesn't matter that there's a logical explanation, it's still an inconsistency in the interface.

Comment: @mark it is not inconsistent; you never need @postowner to notify the owner of a post about your comment. Period.

Comment: @Jeff, what I mean is that it's inconsistent depending on whether you're commenting to the post owner or to someone else. It's a UI inconsistency, not a logical inconsistency - I get your point too.

Comment: @Jeff: Who *cares* how the notification system handles this edge case. I don't think any of us who object to the behavior has a strong opinion. We're talking about the written *content* of a comment. **Don't mess with my content!**

Comment: @Jason indicating that you are talking to the post owner, *in the absence of any other people talking*, is just as redundant as a "hi fellow coders!" salutation. All comments, by definition, notify the post owner in every possible case. Polluting signal with a bunch of redundant @postowner is the same as polluting signal with a bunch of "hi fellow coders!" Also, if you want to use someone's name without the @ symbol, *nobody is preventing you from doing so*.

Comment: @Jeff, you can't rely on the help link because nobody reads anything. Now where did I learn that? Oh yeah, here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/10/treating-user-myopia.html Learning by example is much more reliable.

Comment: @mark and the example they are learning is, they don't need to do anything special for the post owner to be notified of their comment.

Comment: @Jeff, which is exactly the wrong thing to learn when they try to respond to someone else's comment a few minutes later. This is the essence of the inconsistency argument I'm trying to make above, and the whole point of the answer to which we're commenting.

Comment: @mark it isn't inconsistent; talking to the post owner is always "free", talking to *other people* is the only thing that requires the additional effort of @username. Putting @postowner in the first comment every time works *against* teaching them the correct thing here. Guess we'll just have to agree to disagree here; not adding tons of extra noise to the world is something I feel extremely strongly about.

Comment: @Jeff, I'd like to continue this as a chat: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/399/removing-tags-from-comments Be kind to me, this is my first exposure to the Chat rooms.

Comment: @Jeff, Please do an experiment for me. Query the system and find out what percentage of comments in the previous month that were eligible to start with `@` actually did so. Now repeat the test again in two months. I predict you'll see a sharp dropoff, which would validate this answer.

Comment: I find it really ironic that all of these comments are prefixed with "@username".  Isn't that proof enough that this change should be revoked?

Comment: @dave the average number of comments on a Stack Overflow post is .. wait for it.. one. Maybe two. Median is closer to zero. I can't in good conscience live in a world where millions of comments on millions of posts have useless `@postowner` clutter in them.

Comment: @Jeff The prefix is there for context and clarity.  Do you go about deleting parts of answers just because they take up space?  Signatures are one thing; they don't add any value to the question.  These "in reply to" prefixes do add value, because it's extremely difficult to follow comment threads of 4+ comments without them.  I know the content here is cc-wiki, but please don't insult our intelligence by assuming that part of our contributions are inherently worthless and simply "take up space"

Comment: @dave we only remove `@postowner` when the only people talking are the post owner and 1 other person, and there's nobody else the comment could be directed to. Were you unclear about that? Feel free to test it if you don't believe me.

Comment: @Jeff in addition, there are over 600,000 posts on SO that have at least four comments (so about 1 in 10), and nearly 50,000 posts that have at least 10.  So even though the majority of posts won't benefit from the added context, the *long tail* of posts will.  Isn't that what Stack Exchange is about? Catering to the long tail? ;)

Comment: @dave I'd argue the long tail is ~6 million posts (2 million questions) with 1 or 2 comments that all say `@postowner` unnecessarily. We'll just have to agree to disagree here, for the forseeable future. And just as a reminder, if you feel an urgent need to add an "in reply to" in a comment, do the same thing you do in real life: type their name. Like so: Dave. Not so difficult, is it?

Answer (score 77):

I agree.

- The system should minimize instances where it automatically modifies user input.
- If you feel that the system should automatically modify user input, it should allow the user to override. Not allowing the user to override is offensive. Let the user say what they want to say, and if it's a problem, address it by moderation.
- If there is no mechanism to allow the user to override the system, at the very least will you **please** make it provide visible feedback (1) that it is doing so intentionally, and (2) why it is doing so. Otherwise you not only have a system that is not only inflexible and offensive, but also extremely confusing.

---

...and if the sysadmins maintain this as status-declined, then what I'll do is stop using "@" signs, because it just causes annoyance, and I don't want the system automatically censoring my comments.

---

And just for kicks, let's compare these two possibilities.

> Lorem ipsum, etc.
>
> --Fooman
>
> ---
>
> <sup>That doesn't look right.  --Barman</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>@Barman: Are you sure? --Fooman</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>@Fooman: Yes, I am. See "Book of Lorem Ipsum" p. 302 --Barman</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>@Barman: OK, if you insist. --Fooman</sup>

or this:

> Lorem ipsum, etc.
>
> --Fooman
>
> ---
>
> <sup>That doesn't look right.  --Barman</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>@Barman: Are you sure? --Fooman</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>Yes, I am. See "Book of Lorem Ipsum" p. 302 --Barman</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>@Barman: OK, if you insist. --Fooman</sup>

The first of these is symmetric, the second is not. It is **really** strange, when someone writes a comment to you with your @username, to be **completely** unable to respond in kind, without any explanation by the system whatsoever why your use of @username is removed but the other guy's is not.

If some of you think this is excessively noisy, then let it be a client-side preference to remove the @name syntax. But don't change the source comment. If I want to make it clear who I'm talking to, let me do it.

Comment: indicating that you are talking to the post owner, *in the absence of any other people talking*, is just as redundant as a "hi fellow coders!" salutation. All comments, by definition, notify the post owner in every possible case. Polluting signal with a bunch of redundant @postowner is the same as polluting signal with a bunch of "hi fellow coders!" **Also, if you want to use someone's name without the @ symbol, *nobody is preventing you from doing so*.**

Comment: @Jeff: You've said about a dozen times here that "@postowner is the same as...'hi fellow coders'". I think we all understand that you think that. What we're saying is that we disagree. Really quite a lot of us, including people who contribute at a high level to the communities. Regarding your last point, I had to respond to that in the question itself.

Comment: @t.j you can read here for a lot more detail: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/399/removing-tags-from-comments

Comment: @Jeff: Oh, great, let's try to make this even more disjointed and fragmented. *"I'm simply right about this."* I'm sorry, I really am, but you are simply wrong about this. "@Joe" is noise but "Joe" is not? No, that's absurd, it's not even a close call. And I haven't seen any links to "specific harm" in this disjointed conversation. I have seen links to discussions of too much discussion being harmful, which is yet another straw man, I'm not disagreeing with that.

Comment: @Jeff: As with that parenting discussion, clearly your answer here isn't doing the job. I recommend another one, one which doesn't just constantly re-assert your claim that you're right, but actually lays out your points logically and completely, with those citations you talked about, including how you can possibly begin to justify the "@Joe" vs. "Joe" thing, how you respond to the complexity argument. In each case, with real arguments. Not straw men, not "I know I'm right." I also recommend re-opening your mind to the smart people here.

Comment: @t.j I outlined my rationale at length in the above link. This is something I feel extremely strongly about, so we will have to agree to disagee on this indefinitely.

Comment: @Jeff: If that link is it, it doesn't begin to do the job. Re agreeing to disagree: Hey, it's your site. Just remove the *"We don’t run Stack Overflow. The community does."* from http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation and similar if you're going to ignore what dozens of smart people are telling you.

Comment: @Jeff I don't believe people enter the @ so people will be notified.  I think people enter the @ because that is a convention that has evolved over years of BB and twitter use to indicate who you are talking to.  That it will notify them is the last thing on my mind.  I read the whole chat and don't think you have made a satisfying case to justify that @xxx is noise, and xxx is not.  Nor that people enter the @ with the expectation that the person will be notified

Comment: @JockM: "I don't believe people enter the @ so people will be notified" -- EXACTLY! I don't give a damn about how it affects notification. IMHO notification should be done when there are new posts on a question you posed, or new comments on an answer you posted or commented on, or on a question or answer that you explicitly decide you want to be notified about. To notify based on the @tags seems really risky. For one, usernames aren't unique, and for another, people don't always respond with verbatim @username tags (see @Jeff and @t.j in this thread).

Comment: @t.j. the specific harm is this: the average number of comments on a post is two. Multiply that by the ~8 million posts on Stack Overflow times the number of redundant `@postowner` words that are now present on our network. That's a lot of pointless noise. Also note that in the latter example Jason used above, no `@usernames` were required at all to get notifications as we detect when only two people are talking and auto-reply. Bottom line, unless someone explicitly indicates otherwise, *comments are always directed at the post owner*. That's the intent, and has always been from day one.

Comment: @Jeff: Yes, you're clear that *you* believe that notifications are the only purpose of `@postowner`. There's a large number of counters to that on this page. But you continue not to address several points. 1. Even if you were right, it's wrong to push such a silly little thing in the face of this feedback. 2. That's **not** the only purpose of them. 3. The change is pointless, people just put `@ postowner` and `postowner:`, both of which are just as noisy, but which actively mislead new users for when they *do* need to use `@` to direct their comment. I'm sure there are more. #1 is esp. big.

Comment: @t.j. they should just use "Firstname" to address the user, which is fine. I don't object in any way to "Dave, did you consider..", I object to "@dave did you consider.." because it's a) technically 100% incorrect b) teaches new users these same incorrect behaviors and c) extremely noisy.

Comment: @t.j. also, to the extent that people now write "Dave, did you try.." instead of "@dave did you try.." that is 100% the intended result of this change. It's more readable, and doesn't confuse new users. 99% of the time, statistically speaking, *you don't need to use explicit reply notifications at all*.

Comment: @Jeff: I get your point, but it's nearly 100% confusing to anyone who hasn't read this webpage carefully. What you mean is essentially the following: that most of the time `@user:` syntax is appropriate, except in this one case of answerer + one commenter, where the commenter can't add the "@user:" syntax but the answerer can. How is a new user, who may be familiar with Twitter and Facebook and other social media where `@user` is the norm for addressing someone else, regardless of whether it has any automated effect, supposed to understand these rules?

Comment: @$#%@$#%@$%#@%!!!!! I just got a popup saying "Only one additional @user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified" thus denying me the right to use the literal `@user` syntax more than once in the comment even though I was using it in its literal and non-automatic form. You guys REALLY need to take your best shot at a simple, easy-to-understand webpage, and if you really feel the need to deny people posting a particular syntax, include a link to that webpage on the popup box so someone can actually understand what it is they're not supposed to do.

Comment: @Jeff: I had composed yet another reply, and then I got to thinking that things were really very, very fractured at this point and decided to put together pros and cons in handy lists. And somewhere along the way of doing that, the fact that *I'd never offered a constructive alternative* hit me upside the head. That's not how I like to do things. And I've come up with what I think (but then I would) is a pretty good idea: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99261/tell-the-user-who-will-be-notified-of-a-comment

Comment: @jason that link already exists; click the help link under the "add comment" button.

Comment: Quite ironic that Jeff uses the "@t.j" to start his comments...

Comment: "warts and all"

Answer (score 49):

Why must the classification of *signal* or *noise* be binary? Redundant addressing might legitimately fall between the two. Even if you *do* consider it noise, it is the most easily ignored noise possible, always in the same place with the same format.

I believe the downsides of this feature outweigh the upsides.

**Edit:** I believe the proper categorization of the `@` tag is not pure signal or noise, but **redundant signal**. A redundant signal may be removed without changing the meaning of the message, by definition. However you will find that human speech is full of redundancy, because it enhances communication and improves understanding. I would argue for its retention in this case.

Answer (score 40):

*(This is coming at it from a different perspective, so I'm posting an answer rather than editing the question yet again.)*

I think most if not all of the SE sites have the same statement Stack Overflow does: *"[We don’t run Stack Overflow. The community does](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)."*

At this point, some days after this started, more than *<s>seven eight nine</s>* ***ten*** times as many people expressing an opinion want the change reverted as want to keep it. That's a landslide in any voting system. Even if Jeff were right and everyone else were wrong, it would be wrong to persist with it in the face of this kind of community reaction.

The Stack Exchange sites are not a democracy. One person has the ability and in some cases the *duty* to override the community. This is the reality of the Stack Exchange sites and pretty much every other site on the 'net. These are Jeff's sites. He's better than most people in his position about giving power to the community, but if you thought this was a collaborative venture, if you thought you were a partner in the process, you were mistaken. Your suggestions may be taken on board, or they may be disregarded and your post expressing them deleted, or locked for months on end preventing you even replying with a comment. Maybe it's possible to have a truly community-run site, but I've never seen one. There are going to be occasions when that one, finally-responsible person has to override the community's will.

But in a place that purports to respect the community, put it first, let it run the show, that one person needs to pick his occasions with ***extreme*** care. It's not that this change isn't in the same ballpark as something worth rejecting the community over, it's not even in the same *country*.

*"We don't run Stack Overflow. The community does..."*

Those are easy words when you agree with the community, or just mildly disagree. The real test is when you strongly disagree. Persisting with this kind of change in the face of this kind of opposition to it demonstrates ***tremendous*** disrespect for the community and puts the lie to those words.

Let's not go there. Instead, say "The community is wrong. I'm right. But even so, I am going to accept the community's decision on this."

Comment: It's possible that "run Stack Overflow" means moderating, not designing. Jeff isn't interested in the vote because he's not looking at the immediate impact, he's looking years down the road. I still don't agree with him, but I hope I understand his perspective.

Comment: @Mark: Jeff Atwood has at some points taken a very active role in moderating math.SE, often to the consternation of many of the elected moderators and the vocal users of the site.  His single-handed interventions resulted in the resignation of one of the elected moderators.  I was often surprised, among other things, that the head of a largish enterprise would insist on acting on such a small scale: e.g. policing individual comments.  When pressed, he has made it clear that he will do what he wants even if most or all of "the community" is against him.

Comment: @TJ: +1.  I strongly agree with most of what you say.  However I disagree that (let me shift away from the personal) the SE platform gives an unusual amount of control to the user.  It seemed that way at first, but in the long run I have never been involved with a website that took such an active interest in directing and micromanaging my actions.  Protocols on the SE sites change frquently, without warning, and most often without local explanation: you have to go somewhere else (e.g. here) to understand why the site doesn't work the same way today as it did yesterday.

Comment: @Pete: Let's not bring the Robin Chapman thing into this discussion (or did you mean someone else?). It's an unrelated point and one where (agreeing with your post on the matter) neither party appears to have behaved well. It's true that SE changes regularly and I'd agree those changes are not well-communicated. *In general,* I'd say it changes for the better, and it makes a change from systems that just never improve, year-on-year.

Comment: Don't let numerics fool you. Numerics don't make right. *Hundreds* of users were opposed to the changes made to the envelope we used to have. See where we are now. Policies here have never been decided solely by votes. If they were, the top entries in the `reqs` tab on the front page wouldn't still be there, they'd be implemented straight-away. Singular users have been enough to oppose the Team's solid stances and *still* get what they want implemented. Claiming that all these voting supports should be what defines how the site is created is a non-starter.

Comment: @Grace: And I'm not claiming that. I'm saying that the change is pointless, arbitrary, and unnecessary. Forcing a pointless, arbitrary, and unnecessary change down the throats of the community the face of *overwhelming* feedback to the contrary is demonstrating a complete and total lack of respect for that community and an unwillingness to examine or question oneself. The numbers just prove how unpopular it is. It was *wrong* before the first person voted; ignoring the feedback is a second, distinct, error. And a worse one, frankly.

Comment: @TJ: I was not talking about Robin Chapman.  (Actually Robin Chapman is apparently still a moderator...) I was talking about the resignation of Akhil Mathew.

Comment: @Pete and after reading his resignation the loss seems sad.  Without getting into the cause, he seems like a valuable member of the community to lose

Comment: @JockM: yes, Akhil Mathew is, in just about every sense I can think of, an exceptionally good person.  But he hasn't left the community -- he just stopped being a moderator.  So, although I brought it up as an example of negative consequences of outside intervention, I have to say that in absolute terms it wasn't really a tragedy.

Comment: @Pete I take your point (and actually knew that), but I would argue that it is still a net loss.  Just, perhaps, not as grave as it could have been.  As a guy who started and ran a community based website for years I know that any community site is only as good as the leaders in it.  They are the moderating force, they set the tone; in short: they lead.

Comment: @JockM: Sure, when a great moderator is driven to resign on principle it seems clear that something is amiss (which is why I brought it up in the first place).  I just didn't want to paint *too* dire a picture.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark. Jeff Atwood also made some *interesting* moderation decisions on EL&U. He eventually realised his mistakes and issued a notpology.

Comment: "*ten times as many people expressing an opinion want the change reverted as want to keep it. That's a landslide in any voting system.*" Your question has 262 in agreement, and 15 in disagreement. Given there are "millions" of users on Stack, that's no representative of "community". Even with 5K views, it's also, quite specifically, a representative of "Meta community" voting, and the majority of the whole "Stack community" have not even read this.

Comment: @James: The key part of that quote was *"expressing an opinion"*. You can only measure what you can measure. (And it is, of course, now closer to **20** times as many than to ten...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, one can "only measure what you can measure", but that doesn't make it accurate. And one can make a decision without considering the data *because* it's limited and so not particularly useful. Jeff obviously believes he did what was best for the site, and that will (likely) include the presumed consensus from those who did not come here and vote. That's only speculation of course, and it does touch towards dictatorship. But perhaps if 1 million users had come here and voted in favour of your proposal, Jeff would have at least reconsidered it

Comment: @James: Ever interacted with Jeff? **;-)**

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Would stubborn as a mule cover it? No, I haven't, but most people who make big things (like Stack) tend to have strong ideals, that's why they made big things. Not saying it's right, just pointing it out.

Comment: @James: *"Would stubborn as a mule cover it?"* No. Stubborn, in and of itself, one could understand and respect. But Jeff's actions -- including in and related to this question, most of it now carefully edited out -- went far, *far* beyond any acceptable level of behavior. But best to leave it. Not least because this was near the end, and near the end I think he was seriously, seriously stressed.

Answer (score 28):

I know all has been said. I know I cannot upvote twice. Maybe a picture helps. Below, `@ajax333221` was removed, and also [that original author](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/137478/revisions) is not listed as this a community wiki post:

[image: Are you mad? Who you're talking to?]

That bothers me a lot.

Comment: I can see that point, we should special-case CW posts here.

Comment: @balpha. No, you certainly should not special-case CW posts. You should get rid of this entire unnecessary annoying "feature".

Comment: ...but, @balpha, no time to add that exception in the past 2 years, or did you change your mind? (I just saw `@Robert` removed [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th/255584#comment50309_255584), getting me [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ouowv.png)...) Or better yet: maybe it's time to kill that darling and remove the removal code altogether now...!?

Answer (score 14):

I am a mathematics professor who has been very active on both Math Overflow and the newer math.SE.  The help that I give to others on the site is often on the professional level: indeed, a substantial proportion of the hundreds of questions I have answered on that site have required my expertise as a post-PhD mathematician.  Nor has it been one-sided, not at all: there are many other research mathematicians active on the site, including some of the very top ones in the world.  When I talk on this site I talk carefully, and when I listen I listen carefully: there is a lot to learn.

Let us call this latest practice what is is: a form of censorship.  As an academic behaving in a *de facto* professional capacity, my reaction to my writing being censored is what you would expect: a mixture of bemusement, bewilderment and outrage.  Certain people and organizations have historically had the right to censor, including academic writing.  For the last 100 hundred years or so in the Western world, those who have exercised this right have, usually, given very careful thought to make sure that their reasons for censoring are compelling and necessary.  The exceptions to this rule have become infamous and long remembered.

Many people here have remarked that the reasons given for this censorship are very far from compelling.  In fact it seems to me that they are not reasons at all but rather quickly boil down to *I am the boss, so I can make whatever changes will, in my opinion, improve the site*.  This is true, but as a justification for censorship in a *de facto* academic environment?  Wow.  This is going to be negatively remembered by a lot of people for a long time.

**Postscript**: Some people have said that the SE sites are "wikis" which means that users should expect that others can and will edit their writing.  This is technically true, I suppose, but misses the mark in a lot of ways.  First, the SE sites are not like wikipedia (in which I have been active) since on the latter site all users enter with essentially full editorial privileges, whereas on SE these privileges are carefully graduated as the user becomes more experienced and "trusted".  Second, on math.SE at least, edits to others' questions beyond the level of spelling, formatting and punctuation are done very sparingly: for instance, when I spot what I am convinced is a mathematical error in someone else's answer I do *not* edit it but rather leave a comment and wait for the answerer to respond.  This is respectful and ultimately more efficient -- in most cases the answerer and I (possibly with the help of other commenters) quickly come to an understanding.  When people do edit each others' posts even in rather minor ways they often leave comments saying "I changed X; I hope that is okay with you."  If some user repeatedly made stylistic changes in others' answers without telling them, the community would quickly intervene to put a stop to it.  Third, these edits are edits to the *comments*, which are strongly linked to a particular person.  An analogous change on a wiki would be to make edits in others' signed comments on a discussion page, which everyone has the ability to do and in all my experience on wikipedia no one was stupid enough to attempt.  Fourth, these edits are done automatically and without (public, at least) record: if I edit someone else's answer then -- although it rarely comes to this -- they can simply roll it back: the record of the original is preserved.  Here the original writing is being altered irrevocably *and without even alerting the writer that this is taking place*.  Thus it is censorship of a rather craven variety, the kind that the censors hope will not be noticed.  (But we *have* noticed it, of course, to say the least.)

Comment: -1. Not really related to the original question, IMHO.

Comment: Pete, I agree with you.  If you simply leave off the @symbol, I don't believe it will be auto-removed.  As a PhD in Statistics, I share a very similar desire to maintain professionalism (when it's warranted) and [quirky humor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97565) when it's not.  :O)

Comment: This "leaving errors sit while begging the author to fix them" thing really kinda bugs me. Yes, these sites do aim for a delicate balance between encouraging collaboration and encouraging competition, but... Simply refraining to fix things you *know* are wrong out of some misguided sense of respect for the original author is no more appropriate here than it is on Wikipedia. (I realize this wasn't the point you were intending to make, but my attention was totally derailed upon reading that section)

Comment: @MainMa and yet utterly related to the entire conversation as it has evolved

Comment: @Shog9: your comment seems to assume that respect for the original author is misguided.  If that is true, then the entire academic mathematical community is misguided, because we place a premium on respect for others: even when we're awfully sure that they're wrong, we contact the author and seek consensus before acting on that assumption.  This is a social behavior that has developed over a long time.  One effect of this is that mathematicians are usually quite willing to admit when they've made mathematical mistakes.

Comment: It seems clear to me that in the long run this is an extremely beneficial practice.  Even in the short run it means that there are no "edit wars" as sometimes happens on wikipedia.  Anyway, this is sort of moot because the standards for how much editing is too much editing are discussed and largely agreed upon at the level of the individual site: the platform lets us take whatever approach seems best to us as a community.  Finally, as you say this is evidently a different issue than the kind of automated editing currently under discussion.

Comment: @MainMa: the original question is not a question -- it is a *response* to a recent change in the SE platform.  I wanted to make a similar response, and since mine is, broadly speaking, an assent to T.J. Crowder's response, it seems appropriate to post is as an "answer" rather than as a new "question".  In this situation, as I understand it a downvote should mean that you disagree with the opinion I am expressing.  Is that the case here: do you not believe that the new policy is a form of censorship and/or that it is problematic?  I am interested to know what others think.

Comment: @MainMa: How it is not related? I said I wanted the new practice removed, for my reasons. He's saying he wants it removed too, for his reasons. Seems pretty darned related to me. :-)

Comment: Pete - I'll try to bring this back on-topic then: you're describing a local, cultural norm built up on one site to avoid stepping on each other's toes. The *system* makes no such restrictions - in spite of your claims to the contrary, any user, even an anonymous user, can come on the site and submit an edit; if the users of that site opt to reject it, that's their business. However, the `@name` prefixes are a system input - you use them because the system interprets them as replies and notifies the user being replied to. Surely you don't prefix the names of colleagues with `@` normally?

Comment: And with that distinction made, I can rebut your assertion that no one edits talk-page comments on Wikipedia: this is *beyond* commonplace! The Wiki *system* routinely replaces `~~~~` with a proper signature, and SineBot edits in signatures for users who omit them completely. Here and there, if you don't want to deal with the system's behavior, then avoid invoking the system - and invoking the system is the only good reason to begin your comment with an @.

Comment: @Shog9: "and invoking the system is the only good reason to begin your comment with an @" -- That's just crazy. The only reason *I* begin a comment with an @ is to make clear to someone that I'm talking about a person. Remember that we have lots of people who have usernames that are acronyms or trade names or plain lowercase words, like @unwind and @chaos and @Eclipse and @MSN. The "@" disambiguates between a username and a plain word or proper noun. It's good for promoting clarity. Please stop trying to treat this as a pollution issue.

Comment: @Jason: I haven't *started* treating this as a pollution issue yet... But since you brought it up, Jeff thinks starting a comment with superfluous greetz is pollution; personally, I consider that akin to claiming gum wrappers make the city dump look *untidy*. You know what I blame for this? Twitter. Every time I open that wretched site, I'm blasted with a wall of @names and @RT and #hashtags and other assorted meta-crap that isn't worth reading but must be parsed anyway. So I have a hard time getting worked up about anything that makes comments here look *less* like that. But that's irrelevant

Comment: ...because the fact of the matter is, if you want another user notified of your response here, you generally have to use the `@name` construct. It's how the system works. There are plenty of other ways (most of them much, much older than The Internet) to make it clear that you're addressing someone, Mr. S. And they all tend to lend themselves to polite conversation better than this crude "AT YOU" shortcut. So whatever other culture you're drawing @name as a greeting from, I'll wager it's both fairly young *and* probably uses them for notifications similar to SE. It's a system-control escape.

Comment: @Shog9: point taken. Not that you've changed my mind, but I get where you're coming from. Aside from the system-annotation aspect of it, what would be the best syntax to clearly address users named "the" and "chaos" and "PC" and "if"? (not asking rhetorically, asking with sincerity)

Comment: @Jason: same way you'd address anyone else: "the, in regard to your comment on the evilness of eval, I think you're exaggerating the danger." ... "I've actually found, chaos, that ArrayList is all you ever need." etc. Yes, this can be a bit confusing for names like "the" or "if" (the latter isn't valid on SE though), but presumably *that's the point of choosing such a name to begin with.*

Comment: @Shog9: I find your analogies with wikipedia to be a bit strained -- for instance users are *informed in advance* that typing ~~~~ will have a certain effect, and this string of characters was chosen to be something that someone is very unlikely to want to type for any other reason.  Also it is possible to opt out of the automatic signature system.

Comment: But that's not really my issue.  The point is that the site designers have implemented programming that automatically searches people's writing and removes portions that are deemed inappropriate: this is unarguably censorship, and it is incredibly disturbing.  In my normal life I am **very used to** being able to express myself however I choose.  Sometimes I will express myself in ways that others wish I didn't or even I come to regret, but that is addressed after the fact, as it should be.

Comment: @Pete: you're the one trying to draw comparisons to Wikipedia; I'm just saying that your claim of immutable comments there isn't really valid. As for the rest... We're working on documentation, and you can most certainly opt-out by simply omitting the @!

Comment: @Pete: it's not unarguably anything; if it was, we wouldn't be here arguing about it. You may find it irritating that the system treats words prefixed with `@` in a special way, but this is the nature of the system - there are other special characters and character sequences that will also result in changes to the final output of your text, and more will likely be added over time if a need arises. If you find this hampers your ability to express yourself, give us some examples and we'll see if we can find a solution.

Comment: "There are plenty of other ways (most of them much, much older than The Internet to make it clear you're addressing someone..." Indeed.  For instance writing "Dear X" is something that I've done all my life and has been done for hundreds of years.  That is being censored as well: **pre-publication**.  If the community wishes to tell me, "Hey, you're being very old-fashioned with all this Dear X stuff.  We don't appreciate that here because of Y.  We're going to downvote you for it and eventually consider editing it out of your posts" that different because it is **post-publication**.

Comment: This distinction is quite old: for instance Milton wrote about it in the *Areopagitica*.  @Shog9: **No one has yet argued that this practice is not a form of censorship**.  People have argued that it's not a big deal or that it's in the best interest of the site, but that's not the same thing at all.  Could you please explain why you think that this practice is possibly not censorship?  If we can't agree on this we could perhaps consult a legal expert.

Comment: @Shog9: I have to "give examples" why censoring my writing without telling me hampers my ability to express myself?  In 2011??  I'm honestly pretty perplexed by this.  As I said, John Milton wrote about this in 1644; I'm not going to do a better job than he did.  I am definitely operating under the assumption that the SE team are participating members of modern Western society, so that if you stepped back from the particulars of this issue, you actually understand quite well what I am saying.  Right?

Comment: @Pete: if you're talking about the routine that removes greetings from *posts* now, that codifies an established community norm (manually editing out greetings). If you want to call this censorship, you're doing so based on a very crude interpretation of the word, and I rather suspect you know that - the connotations, especially in the context of academic writing, are chilling: unpopular or disruptive ideas being squelched to avoid upsetting the powers-that-be, etc. Trimming superfluous verbiage to improve layout doesn't inspire the same emotional response. Censor vs. Editor...

Comment: @Shog9: My guess is what you actually mean is something like this: "Censorship is a harsh and even somewhat loaded word.  When you use it, you imply that something really bad is being done.  But this is so minor that you should be able to easily adjust to it, if you notice it at all."  To that I say: yes, stripping away things like Hello, Dear X and @Y are quite minor as far as censorship goes.  The time to complain about censorship is when it starts up a little bit, not when it gets totally out of hand (I imagine complaints are harder at that point).

Comment: @Pete: I'm have a really, really hard time understanding why anyone, on either side of this discussion, cares enough to put so much emotion into their writing here. So yeah, if you could give me an example of how your ability to express yourself suffers from being unable to prefix some comments with an `@` symbol, it would go a long way toward helping me empathize. You don't have to; if you're arguing for principle rather than any practical outcome, just say that - I'd understand at least.

Comment: @Shog9: Manually editing out greetings is not done on math.SE and certainly not in any other community that I belong to.  But again the distinction here is between doing something manually after the fact that leaves a record and doing something automatically before the fact that leaves no record.  Just so you know: that someone who is designing code for a webpage thinks s/he can decide in advance which of my writing is "superfluous verbiage" inspires a profoundly negative emotional response in me.  As a form of censorship, it is significant to me.  Please be aware of that.

Comment: @Shog9: it's both.  It really does hamper my ability to express myself, and *on principle* I get upset when you write routines to mess with my writing before anyone can see it.  And not just me -- this is centuries of social precedent.  I do think it's most important to appreciate that.  But since you ask...

Comment: @Pete, re: slippery-slope: yeah, there's a Rev. Niemöller quote that might apply... Again, if you're arguing on principle, that's fine. I began my involvement here to defend a principle of my own... But while this system was designed around the belief that collaborative editing is critical to maintaining accurate, high-quality information, some such as yourself eschew this in favor of other practices. In this case, both the system and moderation policies allow compromise, without which I doubt you would be here at all. I trust you see the value?

Comment: When I make a comment to an answer, I could for instance be adding something else mathematically to the answer, or I could be engaging the OP directly.  It definitely changes the meaning if you strip away the @username entirely.  For instance if I write: "@A: Theorem B holds" then I am drawing Theorem B to the attention of user A, and thereby implying that she doesn't know Theorem B already.  If I omit @A, then I am directing it to whoever may be reading the question.  If the @A gets stripped away a "Yes, I know Theorem B.  Why are you suggesting I don't?" response may be coming.

Comment: So, yes, this has effects, including possibly offending someone whom you had no intention of offending.  Yes, you can work around this by remembering to omit the @ in this situation (or in other ways that I will not get into here).  But now I have to keep in my head some fairly complicated site mechanics just to carry out a mathematical conversation: thus my ability to express myself is *actually* hampered.

Comment: @Pete: thank you, I can appreciate that such a comment might cause ambiguity. The counter-argument here seems to be that comments are *intended* to address the author of the post, and should always be interpreted that way in the absence of evidence to the contrary... However, I've personally found this cumbersome before when dealing with users new to the system. As a work-around for now, simply omit the `@` and the system should ignore the name. This is less than ideal, however if you should forget comments *can* be edited to correct.

Comment: @Shog9: I am all for collaborative editing.  This is done between people in a way which is best for them both.  Writing programs to change my writing is not collaboration: it is, again, **censorship**.  If SE feels that some censorship is necessary to run the site, that is your right.  I'm not telling anyone what to do.  I'm explaining why this is incredibly problematic to me and, by implication, to a lot of the high-quality users the site should be courting, not alienating.  In the long run other sites roughly similar to SE but without these problematic features will spring up, of course.

Comment: @Shog9: Thank you for your help, but I am well aware of workarounds to the "feature".  As with the OP, I am not asking a question here.  I am expressing a serious frustration with the system.  I think by now you've understood well what it is that I find problematic.  That's all I wanted: to express myself.

Comment: @Pete: I found your answer here over-the-top (and, in the case of the editing comparison in the postscript, actively harmful). Your comments have been far more useful to me in understanding your position. I'll respect your beliefs WRT editing and avoid modifying this post, but highly suggest you revise it to clearly state your motivation for responding, fears regarding the direction this change indicates, and example of the difficulties that can arise from its implementation. Thank you!

Comment: @Shog9: Anyone who is interested in the further elaboration of my position can read the exchange in these comments.  I am trying to look on the bright side that you have chosen not to edit my answer.  (The fact that you considered editing my statement of opinion because you found it over-the-top is again very surprising and distressing.)  If I have failed to express myself clearly when describing my own opinions, beliefs and cultural experiences, then I will be the one who has to live with it.

Comment: @Pete: I expected you *would* find it distressing, hence my discretion; regardless of how I feel about the manner in which you express yourself, it is the policy of the site that the original author's wishes be respected. You've made some good points here in the comments, but if your intentions are to stick with what you originally wrote, then this is your prerogative - may your words have the full effect you hoped for when writing them!

Answer (score 12):

I agree with T.J. on this and will add my own additional reason why this disturbs me: because this means that SO (but really Jeff) is exerting editorial control over the style of what I wrote.  If there is something offensive (or such) in my content, I accept that is the responsibility and duty of the moderator.

But when you alter the nature of what I write, *simply because you don't like it* -- and let us face it, this is what it boils down to.  Because I don't think you can point to an objective measure of what constitutes noise and what doesn't.  It is based on what you prefer.

And look, it is great to have a coherent vision, it is what shapes the greatest products, and I expect you do it in what you write and how you present SO; however when it extends into editorial control over MY style, that crosses a line with me.

I wasn't entirely joking when I suggested your filters might remove (or add) oxford comma's next.  While it seems silly it is hard to see a consistant philosophy that says it is OK to remove greetings (a verbal lubricant that dates back to the mists of time), but not something like the [Oxford comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma).

**Addendum:**  I am not -- in chicken little like way -- trying to say that the sky is falling and SO is editing for content willy-nilly.  What I am trying to say is that "clutter" is a deeply deeply subjective thing; and Jeff hasn't even attempted to explain why greetings and @postowner are clutter.  He has simply asserted that they are.

And I do not feel it is appropriate to edit other peoples words for style.

**Update:**  And this is it, my final words on this matter -- and possibly my final contribution to SO:

It seems to be there are such bigger forms of noise to address on this site, than to make an arbitrary decision, for an arbitrary definition of noise (because I **still** haven't seen you give an objective definition of what counts as noise), and enforce it by fiat over the protestations of the community with nothing more than an assertion that you are right.

You *insisted* that the redundant "@postowner" should be removed because it is noise, and then say that a simple "postowner," is not.  This simply makes no sense.  It seems like you are acting like that @ convention started with SO and has a single universal understanding of its purpose and meaning.  But it didn't start here.  It started on other bulletin boards, and forums, and places like twitter; with the purpose of indicating who you are talking to.

I will reiterate what I said in a comment below: I simply do not believe people enter @postowner with a thought in their mind that it will notify the post owner.  They do it to indicate who they are talking to.  So in that sense their intention is exactly the same as "postowner,".

I think SO has a bigger problem.  More than once I have heard colleagues make the comment that they don't participate in SO because they don't like the community.  That they feel it is filled with blunt arrogant responses, and that it doesn't feel welcoming.   So they reap the benefits of SO without contributing.

Actions like this one, and removing salutations and thanks, take out the kind of vital social lubricant needed to make SO feel less clinical and more collegial.  Each time turning SO into a place for people like @sixlettervariables (I am not picking on you sir, but you expressed your opinions rather definitively, and thus make a good example), and less for people like me.

My example is anecdotal, so I cannot say how large it is, but I urge you to take it seriously.  Because if you want So to grow, and thrive in the future, then THIS is the kind of signal v. noise you would be worrying about.  The one that gets more people to be active and contributing.

All this experience in contributing has done for me is convince me you flaunt precedent (the use of @postowner on other sites, ignoring the social niceties that help make us more individual and relatable, and how links are styled; to name a few), in favor of views you *feel* are right, but simply cannot prove.  Contributing hasn't been a positive experience for me, and it just makes be want to go back to my previous leach status.  Which is what I am likely to do.

Look at the votes on your own answer in this matter.  Clearly there are more than a few people who disagree with you on this, but you refuse to acknowledge this this with any kind of meaningful response on this, or respond with any kind of citation that shows that removing @postowner, greetings, or thanks has **any** meaningful affect on the readability and comprehension of conversations here (because ultimately that is what Signal v Noise is about).

I am simply right about this...

Comment: There are excellent reasons to leave the @reply intact, but IMO, this isn't it; the SE sites are wikis, and other people *will* edit your words.

Comment: This is a bit over-dramatic. No one is censoring your speech or putting words in your mouth. The system is just removing some clutter. If the system *could* also automatically correct comma usage accurately, I don't see how that would be a bad thing either.

Comment: Define clutter.  Define clutter in such a way that you could clearly say greetings are clutter, and oxford commas are not; without simply asserting that.  Greetings are a natural part of out speech so editing them out is a form of censorship.  You may find it to be an acceptable form of one, but it is still one

Comment: Greetings and salutations are an eye sore. In my other job I've got to fix your problem no matter how nice or rude you are, why can't SO be the same? So save the time writing "Hello" or "Thanks" and include more code or debug output. Then again, I'm a left brained person who just wants folks to get to the point...

Comment: `I do not feel it is appropriate to edit other peoples words for style.` <-- Welcome to the StackExchange network. People's words are going to be edited for style, whether the system does it or not. If someone is going to take the time to edit a question or answer to fix typos and such for you, they should not have to clear it with you first. They're working for you to make your question better! As much as I don't like the change to automatically remove things, my content being edited is the least of reasons I might be unhappy.

Comment: @BillyONeal There is a difference between editing for content and editing for style.  Fixing typos and/or punctuation is not the same thing as changing the tone or writing style.

Comment: @sixlettervariables but that is a personal choice, I have no objection if YOU don't want to write them, but I do object if you want to edit what I write to change my style

Comment: @JockM: If I changed your variable names on SO, that'd be changing your style. Likewise if I only switched "doesn't" to "does not", that'd be changing your style. If I removed a "please help me" or a "thank you for your time good sirs and ma'ams", that'd be editing out extraneous fluff.

Comment: @sixlettervariables give me an objective measure of why that is "extraneous fluff".  I think you just have a matter of taste, and I think the standard for editing peoples content should be much hight than an arbitrary feeling about taste

Comment: @JockM: You didn't address the OP in your answer, "Dear T.J. Crowder", nor did you end it with "Sincerely, JockM" (I'm sure T.J. thought that was pretty rude `</sarcasm>`). These are equally extraneous. You cannot glean anything from "Hello" or "Thank you!!!!11!1one" which helps you answer their question (besides the obvious, "have you *actually* read the FAQ before posting on SO?"). Edits, manual or automatic, should increase signal and decrease noise.

Comment: While I'm not sure I've seen it said quite so succinctly, I think most of the "rulings" on these types of issues are consistent with a "get to the point" philosophy.

Comment: @sixlettervariables I don't want to enforce a style of mandatory greetings or endings **in exactly the same way** I don't want it enforced by automatically removing them.  I am saying that what is signal and what is noise in these cases has no objective measure.  They bother you, clearly, but they don't bother me (nor most people I know).  So in that regard I agree with you that "Edits, manual or automatic, should increase signal and decrease noise", and would argue that if you cannot **prove** that something is signal or noise you shouldn't touch it.

Comment: @bemace You see a '"get to the point" philosophy', whereas I see a culture of agressive bluntness, and a lack of courtesy -- which is not the same as being discourteous.  And that is part of the reason why I haven't been an active member, because I find nothing engaging about engaging here.  And so I am a leach, reaping the benefits of of the site; but not contributing.

Comment: You know, those Oxford commas *are* a bit of an eyesore... ;-)

Comment: No, but seriously, within a question things like "Hi Fellow Coders!" may be standard social lube, but they don't increase clarity and thus removing them doesn't decrease it; for me, it's a different category. Removing the @ direction *does* reduce clarity. Irrespective of the notification system, comments may not be directed at the post owner. There's a difference between "Be careful doing this, it can bite you" and "@postowner: Be careful doing this, it can bite you." To remove my explicit direction when commenting is the thing I believe is wrong, unnecessary, and a waste of time.

Comment: @T.J. Oxfort commas are orthogonal and should be preferred by all engineers ;)

Comment: @Jock: I was just joking. I understand them, prefer them, and always use them. ;-)

Comment: @T.J. and @JockM: I actually don't care for the @ change, but not because of some editorial/style reason.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Style is Jock's thing. Mine is the reduction of clarity, the unnecessary-ness, the waste of time (they're already having to fix bugs in it, and as any software developer will tell you, adding complexity increases maintenance hassles), and the intrusiveness. SO is wiki-like, I expect people (*people*) to edit my content to an extent. I don't expect a mindless system to strip out my explicit direction, which I've included for clarity, being (again) marginally smarter than the SE engine. :-)

Comment: @T.J.: it messed with my workflow, that's my only gripe. Not enough to join your side, but enough to upvote ;)

Comment: @T.J. There is more at stake than simple clarity.  I very much doubt if you did comprehension tests on posts with greetings and signoffs; and ones without that there would be any difference, and no one is attempting to come back with any kind of proof, just opinion.  But removing this social lubricant can go a long way to making SO seem dryer, gruffer, less welcoming, more blunt.  I encourage anyone to come back with a link to a study or test (or the like) that shows that removing any of these things has any effect on clarity or comprehension.

Comment: @Jock: Fair 'nuff. I don't particularly perceive it that way (although I'm always bothered leaving off a saluation when *asking* a question; curiously not when answering), but I can see how someone would.

Comment: @JockM, unfortunately in this case the only opinion that matters is Jeffs. His is so tightly held that I'm not even sure proof would sway him, if all it proved is that there's no difference - you would need to prove that the lack of greetings was actively harmful, and there's a good chance that the proof would still be rejected.

Comment: @Mark And that is a shame.  I personally believe that (to quote Carl Sagan) "extraordinary claims require extraordinary proof."  I can understand people who say greetings and thanks are not required.  But to turn not required into damaging noise without a shred of any kind of any kind of proof makes no sense.  But that's ok it's Jeff's playground, and I don't have to stay...

Answer (score 9):

Just a reminder of how this came to be (old timers please correct me if I'm wrong).

In the beginning, there were no comments at all, but when comments were implemented, people intuitively started @ing each other. They also had to F5 like crazy to check for answers, since only the post's author was notified of comments.

Then came notifications, the envelope, the SuperCollider. By popular request (and not without some resistance, IIRC) @ comments were added to notifications.

But people kept *forgetting* to add @, and complained that it was redundant anyway for a first comment. So notifications were tweaked such that if only one person besides the post's author had commented, he would be notified of new comments as well.

The change that is the subject of this discussion was the 'logical' next step: remove redundant @ when only two people (post author and someone else) were commenting, since both of them get notified anyway.

---

So what?

Mostly, what I want to emphasise (other people have called this out in comments here), is that *originally* (at least), using @ wasn't about notifications, it was about indicating who the comment was addressed to. In other words, *I think that a valid use case is a 'general' comment on a post which isn't directly addressed to the author, but to all readers.* The fact that the author will be notified is not directly relevant in this case.

Comment: I've made a small correction to the timeline regarding the introduction of post-author notifications - they've been around longer than anything else, since comments were *originally* intended primarily as a way to communicate with the post author. The recent change to notifications is somewhat more subtle, but as you noted does help to explain the logic behind the redundant @ rules. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user/433#433) for another overview of how messaging has changed over time.

Comment: @Shog9, thanks, I did attempt to look up some of the oldest feature requests, but either they're not there, my search-fu is bad, or I gave up too quickly... :)

Answer (score 5):

If the system auto-notifies the post owner, great, but removing @postowner from comments is another matter.

This is messing with the contextual clues we get while reading through comments, and the resulting inconsistencies are subtle and manifold.

Here are examples of just two issues that—even without any of the others—should be sufficient to demonstrate that the feature should be reversed:

- Like many online communities, ours is made up of individuals with an unlimited variety of made-up names. Many of these names are words that are in common use in the English language. This means that even assuming I remember to type "postowner" instead of "@postowner", thereby ensuring the system will post what I've typed, this is all very well when I'm addressing user Joe, but confusion may arise when I'm addressing user Agree or user Cobblers.
- The first point is exacerbated when a post already has several comments, meaning the foot of the post bearing the poster's name may not be visible at the same time as my comment. Worse, just as I post my comment, another user posts a comment that arrives before mine. The resulting impression is that my comment, lacking as it does its @postowner text (and possibly starting "Agree" or "Cobblers") is a reply to that last comment, when it is in fact a reply to the post owner's last comment.

Answer (score 3):

One could argue that removing parts of my comment without a clear notice is a violation of the CC 4.0 license from SE's part. Unlike previous versions of the license, marking modifications is mandatory in 4.0: https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/License_Versions#Modifications_and_adaptations_must_be_marked_as_such .

Comment: I'd reason it is a trivial modification, and no notice is needed. If you wan't to know who of us is right you'll have to go to court....

Comment: @Luuklag True, ultimately; but it's not hard to construct examples in which this change alters significantly the meaning of the comment: for instance comments that contain a pun with OP's username, or use OP's name in the @-notification as part of a sentence.

Answer (score -16):

The `@Felix` was stripped out automatically because it isn't necessary when you leave a comment for the OP.

The assumption is that unless you address your comment to someone else, it must be for the OP.

Comment: I know. I think I made it clear in my bug report that I know *why* it happened. My point is that it's inappropriate.

Comment: So you agree with what I said ... I wonder who disagreed?

Comment: I did, because all your *original* answer did was repeat what I said in the question about why it happened. (Your edit goes a bit further.) Again, I know *why*. That is not the point.

Comment: I disagree, it's inconsistent. It causes confusion to the user when sometimes the @username is removed and other times it isn't.

Answer (score -72):

We remove @postowner for the same reason we automatically remove salutations from posts, like

> Hi Fellow Coders,

(Note that this is only removed when **the only people talking in comments are you and the post owner.**)

The @postowner is unnecessary because the post owner is *always* notified of every comment in every circumstance.

Adding unnecessary name references in comments is yet more words on the page that we have to ignore -- exactly like unnecessary salutations -- so it is ultimately harming the signal-to-noise ratio on the comments.

Comment: I disagree, it's inconsistent. It causes confusion to the user when sometimes the @username is removed and other times it isn't. I just saw your comment about not needing it when replying to the postowner, what if you're the postowner replying to a comment?

Comment: The trouble is people get weirded out by having their comments changed for them.  Did the ping go through?  Did I do something wrong?  Should I leave them a note somewhere else, like on a different post or in chat?  Is it a bug?

Comment: I disagree. Sometimes the comment is addressed to particular person and without the @ reference it doesn't make sense. So actually removing it harms readability of the page.

Comment: I tend to agree with Jeff. @othercommenter makes sense, but postowner doesn't.