# When removing @lerts, remove full user name with spaces

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, comment-replies, automatic-edits

In situations where [an @lert is removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation/97099#97099), if the commenting user included a full user name with spaces, only the leading portion of the @lert that doesn't contain any spaces is removed.

For example, in my case people often address @lerts to:

> @Rick Sladkey: What about...

and these comments are modified so that they look like this:

> Sladkey: What about...

Although [spaces in @lerts are not supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), through abuse of the syntax this type of @lert is fairly common.  It would be helpful if the rules that removed @lerts could support spaces in the user name so that the commenter doesn't appear to be addressing the post author by his/her last name.

Unlike questions, comments can only be edited by the author so other users cannot fix cases where the removal isn't ideal.

Comment: How could people be using comments wrong, there's a help link that [solves all problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97283/dont-remove-the-part-of-my-comment#comment-244960)

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: That would be quite outlandish indeed- oh noes, i did it again...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is already implemented – after you mentioned this in a comment to Jeff – just not deployed yet.

Comment: Is it deployed yet? Still broken here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577906/is-size-of-the-object-affected-by-type-of-access-specifier-and-type-of-inheritanc/6578021#6578021

Comment: @BillyONeal: No, it wasn't. But it is now.