# What patterns are used to determine if a comment @-addresses the post's author?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happened to my @ salutation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/what-happened-to-my-salutation)

Out of curiosity, what kind of pattern is being used here. It worked beautifully when I made a comment like:

`@poster - blah blah` and it became `blah blah`

Comment: @Rick - I am asking the specifics of how it works. What situations have been considered etc.

Comment: @Rick Not a duplicate.  This isn't asking WHY it's happening, it's asking HOW it happens.

Comment: I think it's clear -- if the person would be automatically notified, it's removed.

Comment: @agf - come on, I mentioned that even in the question. I realize the why, I just wanted to know what patterns are being considered. Like how the `-` is removed, is something like `:` considered and so on. This more from the code point of view how this is implemented. Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @manojlds: Sorry, now I understand.  The rules are shockingly complex as documented here: [How do comment `@`replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).  Removal is even more complicated due to user names [with spaces in them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97421/when-removing-lerts-remove-full-user-name-with-spaces).  I cannot find documentation that whitespace between the username and the single character of punctuation is also taken into account.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Trying to reopen it