# Alert users as to why their @lert is being removed from comments

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comment-replies

While [I personally despise this change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97283/dont-remove-the-part-of-my-comment), so long as we have to live with it it needs to be made clearer to new users. I've seen people who are not aware of the @ syntax's affect on notifications get confused. For example, see the second comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577906/is-size-of-the-object-affected-by-type-of-access-specifier-and-type-of-inheritanc/6578021#6578021).

If the system is going to edit the user's content for them in this way, then the user should be told what is going on.

Comment: It could be another pen graphic (in red or something so it's a different color from the one placed there if the user edits) next to the comment to let the user know if it's been edited by the system.

Comment: @Jonsca: I don't think that really solves the problem though. Then the new user just goes "what the hell is this red pen thing?"

Comment: Just like we all went "What the hell is this pen thing next to my comment" the first time.  It can have a mouseover to explain just like the "This comment was edited" you get from the black pen graphic.  Anyway, just a quick suggestion that popped into my head.

Comment: @Johnsca: An on-hover notification like that might work. Still think that might be misleading though. I would rather see a textual notification to the user.

Comment: Why not both? No, just kidding, a text notification could be useful, it's just a little obtrusive is all.

Comment: I agree...send a notification about this, please.

Comment: I agree, the automated disappearance without explanation [confused me repeatedly](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/690558#690558). **Visible change** — for example, removal of white space — can help the user to learn. **Invisible change — complete removal without explanation** does nothing to help learning.

Comment: @Graham try also to start a post with "Hi" and probably also "Hello" and see what happens.

Comment: @ShadowWizard hi, sorry, if that comment appeared ill-mannered or terse. I said [please three times](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/690546#690546) in the chat that preceded (linked from my previous comment), thanks three times, and [a smiling goodbye](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/690595#690595). Here in Q&A I assumed that it's good form to not be too chatty/familiar in comments, especially with people I don't know personally — it's so often seen "not a discussion forum" etc. :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Don't remove the @ part of my comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97283/dont-remove-the-part-of-my-comment)

Comment: @ʇolɐǝzǝɥʇqoq no it's not. One clearly asking "don't remove" the other asking "alert when it's removed".

Answer (score 3):

This is a good idea to help mitigate confusion over a controversial change.

It seems like it would be pretty easy to do, and the same method as the `Consider adding a comment to the question` popup could be used.  It's unobtrusive but noticable:

> The @alert at the beginning of this comment was removed as it is unnecessary.  See the comment help dialog (under the **ADD COMMENT** button) for more information.

Comment: Upvoted, but the current help is wrong. The system undoes what the system (in the current help) tells the user to do.

Comment: @graham no, the current comment help is correct. Try clicking the help link under the [add comment] button and read it yourself.

Comment: @Jeff hi, I **did** read help repeatedly before seeking help in meta chat. Both **help areas are misleading**. Inline help states: "… To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name …". Clicking *Learn more…*, the [Markdown help for Replying in comments makes very clear that I should mention the username, and make it clear who I am responding to. The person I replied to had a three-character username (the minimum)](http://www.wuala.com/grahamperrin/public/2011/08/03/a/?mode=gallery), so I was repeatedly confused by the help.

Comment: @Jeff sorry I think I realise my mistake. You were probably right to raise your voice! I was thinking of someone as a commenter — without noticing that the commenter was also the poster. Part of the problem for me (not perfect eyesight) is the **pale blue text on white background** at Ask Different. The **lack of contrast** bit me once before, in a different way. I'll mention the contrast issue away in that stack. Sincere apologies for the confusion. Still I do think a subtle hint/explanation at time of disappearance could reduce the risk of confusion :-)

Comment: As promised: [Is the pale blue of texts — on white and pale blue backgrounds — too pale at Ask Different?](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/q/638/8546)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to understand how comments work, there is already an on-screen display. Simply click the "help" link under the Add Comment button.

[image: comment help link, expanded]

Note that **this help is pre-expanded by default for all new users**, so it is effectively mandatory.

Comment: But this help does not contain any hint that @peter is going to be removed, so it's not really relevant to Billy question.

Comment: @Jeff Also the users that are confused are not necessarily new.  In the example link that user had 10k rep.

Comment: +1 - That actually solves my biggest issue. Would it be possible to link to something like this? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97524/list-of-reasons-for-automatic-system-content-modification

Comment: @billy sure we can add a "learn more" link

Comment: -1 — the visible help teaches the user to explicitly address the one commenter. The system inexplicably undoes what the system tells the user to do. An up for @ShadowWizard

Comment: @graham try reading the screenshot again, the text was updated a while ago. **"the post author will always be notified of your comment.**

Comment: Maybe there's confusion — at least for me, maybe also for other relative newcomers — about what is a post, what is a comment. To me: this *post* is an answer authored by poster Jeff Attwood, a response to a post (the opening question) by poster Billy ONeal. Within this one post I see *comments* (not posts) authored by **commenters** Shadow Wizard, JNK, Billy ONeal, Jeff Attwood and me.

Comment: @graham I see, that makes more sense

Comment: I must say it's amusing this got [status-declined] even though what I was looking for got implemented. :)