# SE changes '!' changes to '?' in title

Tags: discussion, automatic-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please remove the s/!/?/ title filter from Metaǃ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102807/please-remove-the-s-title-filter-from-meta)

I posted a question on meta exchange and I had an exclamation mark at the end. The '!' was switched to a '?'. I thought I mistyped it, so I retried and it did it again. WT..

I hate apps which modify things under your feet without a warning or suggestion. Thumbs down for this feature.

Comment: Are you asking for the behaviour to be changed? Just expressing your dislike? What are you hoping to get out of this post?

Comment: Like I said, give a warning when the site is going to change something I typed. I almost missed it and I was never aware of this feature.

Answer (score 0):

This probably happened because it's usually expected that the titles should be in the form of a question.  Using `!` designates an exclamation, not a question.

Comment: There's are tens of thousands of questions on SO and SE sites which are not pure questions and end with a question mark!

Comment: That doesn't make it the right thing to do, @Tony_Henrich. Just means we need to edit and/or downvote and/or close and/or delete tens of thousands of "questions."