# An exclamation point is not a word!

Tags: bug, grammar, popups

I was just editing [an old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575819/sending-a-message-to-deallocated-object-is-working?rq=1) whose title ended with an exclamation point. I left the punctuation; I thought it was appropriate, since the question describes a surprising and counterintuitive situation. On clicking "Save edits", I was presented with this notice:

[image]

We've discussed [the merits of the title filter before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-one-of-the-worst-ideas-ever-implemented-on-so), and I'm not here to talk about that.

I just want to report, and ask for a fix to, the use of "word" to describe the *punctuation mark*.

The box should read:

> ### Please do not use `<list of banned strings>` in titles. See [Writing Good Titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title).

Where <sub><sup>(hopefully this is obvious)</sup></sub> `<list of banned strings>` is replaced by all the bits of text the filter is blocking. This will provide a grammatically correct warning for anything that's in the filter list. (Thanks for [the suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162011/an-exclamation-point-is-not-a-word#comment470900_162011), Matt!)

Or, given that this restriction [only applies to trailing punctuation marks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115327/stop-rewriting-trailing-exclamation-marks-as-question-marks?lq=1) (which is good, since `!` is an *operator* in more than a few programming languages), perhaps some punctuation is worth a special case:

> ### Please do not end your title with an exclamation point. See [Writing Good Titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title).

<sub>(Also, if you're going to capitalize the first word of the second sentence, why not the first? You've also got punctuation ending the first, but not the second, and the old "it's not a complete sentence" argument doesn't apply.)</sub>

Comment: Fixed the title for you.

Comment: Thank you, @Wesley, I should have thought of that!

Comment: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!DO NOT USE EXCLAMATION POINTS IN TITLES!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Why not silently remove it as with full-stops (and maybe auto-add to the low-quality queue!?!) rather than have a kerfuffle?

Comment: And while we're talking about the question filter, WTF? "[please please help....](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14214846/7)" can get added to a title and it _doesn't_ trip the filter?!

Comment: At the risk of further exacerbating the pedantry, can I just point out that changing this will not only require new code, but will also require considering all of the other possible cases where something is forbidden that is not a word?  Is it really worth the effort to fix?

Comment: @Robert: Yes, I know. I expect this will be [staus-declined], given the history of grammar bug reports.

Comment: The sentence could just become "please do not use "!" in titles". This will work for words as well; "please do not use "[closed]" in titles" etc.