# Exclamation(!) turned in to question mark(?) in title field

Tags: discussion, title, quality-filter

I just submitted a question ([Untrusted connection!](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/785/untrusted-connection)) with an exclamation (!) at the end of the title (***with one space*** between the word and the exclamation) but it turned in to question mark (?).

I removed the space between the word and the exclamation, then it shows normal.

Is this an intended feature?

Comment: There [are rules about trailing exclamations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115352), so probably by-design. Why do you need an exclamation point there? It honestly doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @animuson I just want to intimate the warning(!) for untrusted connection.

Comment: Let me check it here... right!

Comment: That's a bug, as the intended behavior is described [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115352/152859): *We're forbidding trailing !s† in question titles on the trilogy, **but they won't be converted to ? anymore** either*

Comment: @BillWoodger I already raised a question for Untrusted connection! here http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: I just confused myself by not reading that you'd edited it yourself afterwards, which was in the grace period, so I saw no record of the edit. Entirely my mistake.

Comment: @ShadowWizard : it’s not a bug, graphic design isn’t part of the original trilogy. It’s the expected behaviour.