# Does a "Me Too" answer really need Moderator Attention?

Tags: discussion, flags

I have searched Meta for this, but I have not been able to find a discussion on this.

We've all seen "Me Too" answers that make no attempt to actually settle the question with a real answer.  We flag them as "Not a real answer." and they go straight to the Moderator queue.

The Moderator queue fills up with thousands of flags that could easily be fielded by non-moderator users.  Can't we trust users with a few thousand rep or some of the realy cool badges (or multiple voting users) to take care of a "Me Too" answer?

Comment: But then how would we get our helpful flags?

Comment: 3 20k users can delete an answer already.

Comment: Why should especially that go to non-moderators?

Comment: No, they don't go "straight to the moderators queue". They first go through the 10K queue.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I was judging from the diamond in the flagging dialog that the question was going to the diamond queue.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Where should I have looked to learn that instead of asking this question?

Comment: @juergend  I'm singling out "Me Too" questions because many of the others are a huge can of worms that already have discussions with verbosity to fill up several MB on SE servers.

Comment: I'm not saying you shouldn't have asked - if you're not a 10K user, you probably don't know about the `/tools/flagged` page. I was simply correcting an assumption you made.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII  Sure, I understand. I just though I might have missed a post or Wiki that explained that.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII  Others may have the same question I did, and I think your comment is the correct answer.

Comment: I wonder if there's a specific permutation that auto converts these to comments. It's [not listed here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97526/).

Comment: The flag review list that 10k users see is not really a separate place from the moderators' flag list, @Richard: the flag is only visible to 10kers  until a moderator handles it. On the other side, the activity of 10kers in that list just adds to the flags; it doesn't somehow approve the flag and push the flagged post up to moderator attention, nor does it dismiss the flag from the moderator list. In short, flags _do_ go to straight to the moderators' queue, but 10kers can see them until they're processed.

Comment: @JoshCaswell however, doesn't 6 flags automatically delete the post? Thus, 6 users = 1 moderator action, correct?

Comment: Only [_offensive_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work) or [_spam_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/how-does-the-spam-flag-work?lq=1) flags have that effect, @Richard, which are not meant to be used on a "me, too" answer.

Comment: @Josh I see, my bad, then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can't we trust users with a few thousand rep or some of the realy cool badges (or multiple voting users) to take care of a "Me Too" answer?

We can, and we do. [Trusted users](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user) (i.e., those with 20k+ reputation) can vote to delete answers with a score of -1 or less. This does not require any diamond moderator intervention; it just requires a consensus of 3 trusted users.

Naturally, it will require that *someone* downvote the answer, but that's not too much to ask. For one thing, the answer needs downvoting if it's literally just "me too" and not an answer to the question. For another, you'll get the rep you lose back after the deletion takes effect, so no whining.

That said, if you're *not* a 20k+ user, you should still continue to flag these "me too" non-answers as "not an answer". That's the only tool you have at your disposal (in addition to downvoting), and they *do* meet the criteria for "not an answer". We want them deleted, and it's worth the time it takes a moderator (and/or trusted users) to process these items. As you've seen, if the flag queue load gets too high, we'll just have to run another election and bring in some new janitors.

Comment: Hi Cody, to make this a 100% perfect answer, you should point out that NAA flags go into the 10K moderator tools queue, so any user with 10K reputation will see these flags before they get to a moderator. You've already pointed out that 20K users can cast delete votes, and NAA flags are one way to ensure a few 10Kers can downvote the poor content so a few 20Kers can then summarily remove it. :)

Comment: For answers that repeat a solution from another answer with some "me too" language, *don't* flag not-an-answer, just downvote even if you can't delete vote.  Moderators don't always look at other answers when handling non-custom flags, and any answer-shaped-object will usually get declined for NAA flags.  (Even if it doesn't actually answer the question being asked.  But in this case it does do that, just redundantly.)