# '@' notation in comment disappearing?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, comment-replies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alert users as to why their @lert is being removed from comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97448/alert-users-as-to-why-their-lert-is-being-removed-from-comments)

I left a comment in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119998/using-wget-in-conjunction-with-an-openid-login), with the format `@Pekka, *rest of comment*`. Upon submission, the `@Pekka,` part disappeared. I edited the comment to re-insert the missing part and after submitting, it disappeared again! Is this expected in any sort of circumstance or is it a real bug?

**Edit**: Just tried again, with a new comment on the same question, and the problem is recurring (thus, the bug is reproducible).

Comment: Yep - the system auto-strips the `@` when it's superfluous.  It's a terrible feature, but that's by design.  And this question closed as a dupe in 5...4...3...

Comment: Cool, Just wondering. Couldn't find the dupe when I searched.