# It's time to revert removing @name from comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-replies, automatic-edits

Yes, I am aware of:

[Eeeeek - what happened to my @ salutation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation)

[Don't remove the @ part of my comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97283/dont-remove-the-part-of-my-comment)

[Alert users as to why their @lert is being removed from comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97448/alert-users-as-to-why-their-lert-is-being-removed-from-comments)

But now that several years have gone by, I think we can step back and agree that the internet got this right, and Jeff got this wrong.  I don't see Github crumbling under the weight of redundant `@mentions`.

I don't use SO that much, and I actually wasn't aware of this gotcha.  But today I got bit by it and it was extremely... frustrating.  First I thought it was user-error, then I thought it was a bug, and finally I stumbled onto the posts above and realized it was a... "feature."

It absolutely violates the [Principle of Least Surprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).  I'm amazed SO never at least met the users halfway and added a clear alert that a comment is going to be munged.

The underlying debate over redundant notifications is just silly, and can easily be solved in software (again, Github doesn't seem to have this problem if I `@mention` someone in a comment who would have gotten notified anyways).

It's time SO acknowledges that this cripples natural internet-speak and changes it. Given the developer who wanted and vociferously defended the change isn't even with SO anymore, I'm hoping this can finally be fixed.

Comment: This has the other advantage of if you are talking to them, agreeing or talking to the world in general.

Comment: The number of ways people misspell my name is amusing, but it gets old after a while. They misspell it because the `@name` autocompletion doesn't work when commenting on one of my answers and there are not enough other comments to require my name.