# please don't delete @name in comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-replies, automatic-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Don't remove the @ part of my comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97283/dont-remove-the-part-of-my-comment)

I can't find out where this "feature" is documented, but I was in a comment thread in electronics.stackexchange.com where I was responding to the poster @stevenvh in a comment, and the name `@stevenvh` (or even `@ste`) was deleted from the beginning of all my comments. For example, if my comment was "@stevenvh: thank you, but I think X", then it posted "thank you, but I think X".

**Please don't do this.** If I have a comment, the system should not delete part of my comment without giving me a way to override. (If you really must continue this behavior, at least give me an indication of why it's doing what it's doing, so that I don't go temporarily crazy wondering why there's a bug in my browser or in Stack Exchange.) There are cases where multiple people may be speaking in a comment thread, and it is important for clarity purposes to indicate who we are speaking to.

Comment: Documented here:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098 and in the features list here:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange

Comment: Already `[status-declined]` -- the future of this feature request looks bleak.

Comment: I don't see why this was done in the first place, and why they already haven't seen that it causes more problems than it fixes (not hard, since it didn't fix anything except for a lack of exact duplicate questions here)

Comment: @won same reason we remove salutations, it's rather easy to understand. Put on your thinking cap.

Comment: @JeffAtwood: I wouldn't consider the two anywhere near similar.  Keeping distractions from questions is extremely important.  Removing redundant @s from comments is as close to pointless as you can get.

Comment: It's bad enough that this question gets posted every 20 minutes; do we need to have the same discussion in the comments every time?

Comment: OK, didn't realize it was a duplicate -- I spent about 5 minutes trying to search for an existing question before I posted this one

Comment: @won keeping pointless references to the post owner, **when the post owner is _always_ notified of every comment on their post, every single time, for ever and ever amen**, is just as noisy as a pointless "Hi fellow coderz".