# Cannot use @name in my comment

Tags: support, comment-replies, automatic-edits

I just commented on a question and I tried to add `@BDuelz:` in front of it but it got truncated.

How come?

Comment: @BDuelz: Is seems to work here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you were probably commenting to the OP and the exchange now strips `@` tags when you are commenting straight to the poster and noone else posted yet.

For example try posting below with the `@Neal` tag and you will see what I mean.

Here is a link all about it: [Don't remove the @ part of my comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97283/dont-remove-the-part-of-my-comment)

Comment: AHA! Ok I see. Can you please post a link to the info about the change if you can find it. Thanks!

Comment: @PeeHaa -- see the link I added to my answer.