# Please make a special case for allowing @postowner in comments, when talking about @postowner

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comment-replies, automatic-edits

The system only allows a comment to have only one @name in it.  Unfortunately if this is a meta discussion about how notifications work, of [the discussion about not deleting @postowner from comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97283/164924), then you get an error message saying only one user can be notified.

Since it is common to use `@postowner` in these comments, please make a special case exemption for that specific literal use.

**Addendum:** to be clear I am talking about the literal string "@postowner" not a @ directed AT the postowner

Comment: See also [Don't block comments with two @alerts if one of them is @postowner](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99015) (possible duplicate).

Comment: @Hendrik In a way, I suppose.  I am not talking about a figurative "@postowner" though.  I am talking about the literal string "@postowner" when talking about that literal as in this comment right here.

Comment: @‍JockM: Hmm, then you'd also have to allow `@lert`, `@all`, `@reply` and stuff like that. As I wrote in a comment to my feature-request, it would be nice if just _all_ invalid @lerts were allowed.

Comment: Regarding your edits: What? No one uses the literal string `@postowner`. That defeats the entire point. *Obviously* you're talking to the post owner if you don't address someone else specifically. And if you're going to address people, at least use their user names...

Comment: @cody yes people talk about the literal string `@postowner` in comments, it has been done a lot in the last couple of weeks in the discussions about the automatic removal of it.  People are using it to talk about @ comments, not some generic reference to the postowner

Comment: Oh, I see. Well then there's a simple solution to that: **stop talking about @ comments**. I'm quite tired of that discussion, anyway. There's no real-world use case for `@postowner`, and a `[feature-request]` so that we can have more meta discussions/rants about something that isn't likely to change is the definition of pointless.

Comment: @cody this is meta, a place where people will talk about all kinds of features of the system.  So there would be no use for this on SO itself, but on meta, yes there is.  Though I am sorry if talking about this bothers you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There already is such a special case exemption: put it in a `@codeblock`

Comment: @Hendrik: how common is putting "@postowner" into your comment?

Comment: @Shog9: In the past days it's very common `:-)` Please note my 2nd comment to the OP, I'm thinking also of other @lerts.

Comment: @Jeff Is there any way I as a end user could have discovered that?

Comment: @Jeff perhaps the error message telling me I can't have more than one `@name` could mention this

Comment: @JockM: Obviously the preference is that you don't use the workaround; including it in the error message removes it from "workaround" status and turns it into "feature" status.

Comment: @cody and I am fine with that.  I don't think Jeff said it was a workaround but a "special case exemption" in which case it is the appropriate way to do that.  So educating the user would be a good thing

Comment: Oh my, what I wrote in my 1st comment was plain wrong: There's no exemption for links; my first comment to the OP just went through because `@postowner` is followed by an `]` from the inline link syntax. @Jeff: Why is there no exemption for this? I'm more and more annoyed at that blocking feature (is this on purpose, for reducing the number of comments?); for a link I don't need codeblocks.

Comment: @hendrik everything you're describing seems like obscure edge conditions to me. Can you perhaps edit your other request to show more real world examples of where this is an issue in practice rather than in abstract theory?

Comment: @Jeff: I've added a few examples to [my other request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99015/dont-block-comments-with-two-alerts-if-one-of-them-is-postowner).

Comment: @Jeff I ask again, short of searching for this post, or trying things at random, how would a user know about this exemption.  Wouldn't it just be clearer for everyone to just allow more than one @ in a comment (but only notify the first), or make the exemption I suggest?