# New rule preventing multiple @notifies causing Convert to Comment to fail

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, moderation, moderator-tools, convert-to-comment

[image: An image is worth a thousand words]

Apparently, an image is not worth a thousand words, as without at least a few words this won't meet quality standards.

Comment: The law of unintended consequences strikes again. Though would encasing the offending strings in back ticks work?

Comment: Let's try `@format` and `@source`

Comment: See also [Don't block comments with two @lerts if one of them is @postowner](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99015). EDIT: Ah, only now I see - this is about _conversion_ to a comment. That's a point I hadn't even considered before!

Comment: How is this "by design", @Jeff? And what's the appropriate thing to do here? Have the moderator manually edit the answer to add backticks before trying to convert it to a comment? (Seems like an answer should generally be posted with a rationale whenever [meta-tag:status-bydesign] is added.)

Comment: @cody the answer is to press the 'delete answer' button, in the screenshot above.

Answer (score 18):

You can work around this by encasing the offending strings in back ticks:

> Curiously, for my `@docType` data, the `@format` and `@source` tags ...

Though this would mean editing the "answer" before converting it to a comment - increasing the processing time considerably.

Comment: So far I've had to edit approximately 100% of the answers I converted to comments anyway; they're almost never perfect