# Allow the moderator comment conversion tool to override the @ limit

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, convert-to-comment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New rule preventing multiple @notifies causing Convert to Comment to fail](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100031/new-rule-preventing-multiple-notifies-causing-convert-to-comment-to-fail)

When converting an answer to a comment, the poster had asked if some Objective-c `@property` type values were set, for example:

---

Do you have -

in .h:

```
NSString * propertyName;
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSString * propertyName;`
```

in .m

```
@syncthesize propertyName;
```

---

Of course, because there's more than one `@` I bumped into this error:

> Only one additional @user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified

This means I have to edit the answer to add backticks before converting. It would be good if we could override for this particular case in the mod tools.

It's not the first time I've encountered this.