# Unable to convert answer with two @mentions to comment

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New rule preventing multiple @notifies causing Convert to Comment to fail](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100031/new-rule-preventing-multiple-notifies-causing-convert-to-comment-to-fail)

As a moderator, I am trying to turn [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/15146/21) into a comment. The answer starts with “@chris @vebjorn”. I get the following (full-page) error message:

> Only one additional @user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified

I think this check should only be applied when a user is posting, not when a moderator is converting an existing post.

I worked around the problem by editing the answer before converting it into a comment.

Comment: Also this seems like a way for a user that cannot comment to change his answer to a comment to circumvent the rules!

Comment: It's annoying but currently the only thing you can do is remove the @s or escape them with backticks