# Don't tell me how to write! ("Only one additional @user can be notified" message)

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications

Ran across the "Only one additional @user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified
(click on this box to dismiss)" message for the first time today and somewhat to my surprise, when I clicked to dismiss the comment didn't go through and I was forced to edit it to actually have it go though. While I can understand there might be some technical reasons (and spam prevention reasons) for this design decision, I do think that we really shouldn't have to edit our comments to have them go through. Perhaps a "Click to post anyway" message can be added so things go through and only the first person in the list gets notified?

To clarify the use case a bit, this was actually over on money.stackexchange.com where two different users both commented on my question and the same answer addressed them both.

> @userOne, @userTwo - Correct, ....

Comment: See also [Don't block comments with two @lerts if one of them is @postowner](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99015), where I proposed similarly that the popup should contain some "I know what I'm doing, submit the comment nonetheless".

Comment: The thing is the system only ever notified (i.e. sent a message to their inbox) the *first named* `@user`. The second *never knew you'd replied* unless they happened to come back to the question/answer.

Comment: I understand the logic of wanting to use two `@user` entries to address two different people - I've often wanted to do this myself - but it's pointless *within the system* to use it as only the first named is notified. If you want all `@user` mentions to notify then that's a different question.

Comment: @ChrisF: Sometimes I refer to one user while commenting to another.  The system should notify the FIRST referenced person.  I'm okay with a notification that the others won't get a notice, just let me go ahead.

Answer (score 6):

Basically you are being asked to remove the extra @user(s).

Since you provided multiple @user's, the system doesn't know which one you want to remove, and leaving extra @user(s) that will never notify creates a broken system.

Comment: One note I will make, should anybody see it and care, is that the 15 second window between comment posting becomes a hindrance in this case, since you so often have your full comment typed out, get the message and so proceed: cut/post/paste/post/declined/wait (you eager bunny!)/post/wait/post.

Comment: What is the rationale for only allowing one user to be notified?

Comment: @glowcoder "Spam" control. Limiting the amount of notifications any one person can make. Plus, it probably makes the system faster, because you only have to search for the first .@user.

Comment: Allow me to rephrase. What is the rationale for limiting the amount of notifications any one person can make? It doesn't seem like there would be any significant downside to allowing more than one @ in a comment. In fact, my preference would be that all users who have commented on a post would be notified any time there is a new comment on said post, but that's just me.

Comment: @glowcoder: What is the use case for having a conversation with two or more people in comments?  The folks at SE probably feel that such a scenario is best handled in chat.

Comment: For starters, when you want to respond to two people regarding two different things in the same comment so you don't have to wait 15 seconds between them. For example: `@First Yes, the foo has to bar the baz. @Second I'm not aware of any xyzzy in my foo, but that's an excellent point!`

Comment: Re: Spam Control: As you stated, just find the first @ reference and send to them.  If there are others you can let the person know it won't go out but give them the option to go ahead and let the comment stick.