# Auto-removal of @name from comments makes the site less readable

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, notifications, automatic-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Don't remove the @ part of my comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97283/dont-remove-the-part-of-my-comment)

A brief scan through similar questions here on Meta revealed that apparently SO staff regards the feature useful for removing noise.

I beg to disagree and humbly suggest that aside from serving as mere notification triggers, **references also indicate the intended recipient to us, readers**.

References make following the discussion easier. Current approach distracts attention every time an unreferenced comment comes up: Are there at least three users involved? Or was the reference simply omitted? To whom was the comment intended for anyway?

**In short, is @name noise really so bad that it justifies inconsistent referencing which distracts more than it helps?**

[Principle of Least Astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)

Comment: ☃@Saul - +1. One of my least favorite anti-features.

Comment: I have found myself editing comments on several occasions; I assumed that I had simply forgotten to put in the `@<user>` part, but my edit didn't really help :-S

Comment: possible duplicate of [Don't remove the @ part of my comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97283/dont-remove-the-part-of-my-comment) Your objection is made explicitly in some of the comments to [Jeff's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97283/dont-remove-the-part-of-my-comment/97290#97290).

Comment: @Cody Gray: The issue of readability is not discussed in the answer you refer to.

Comment: Hrm, I see you're already having trouble reading comments. Notice that I said "made explicitly in some of the comments". Your argument appears to be that these @replies indicate the intended recipient, which increases readability of comments. Billy ONeal made that same argument in a comment. But the point is really that this is unlikely to get changed, whether we like it or not.

Comment: the average # of comments on all posts is two. Having millions of redundant `@postowner` comments on millions of posts with 2-3 comments is a massive reduction in readability. Remember that the post owner is always notified of every comment by default; click the "help" link under "Add Comment" for details.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I suppose simply overlooking Billy's comment is out of the question? But thanks for the clarification. He does talk among other things about disambiguating recepients but also mentions it being irrelevant to him whereas I feel that selective auto-removal of `@name` creates unnecessary distraction.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood - All I am saying is that explicit references reveal the flow of discussion instantly. Otherwise it takes more effort.

Comment: there is no flow of discussion in the typical case; comments address the person "on the podium" (aka the post owner) unless they explicitly indicate otherwise. When someone stands up and ask a question of a person presenting on stage, they are not addressing another random audience member...

Comment: @Jeff Atwood - There isn't automatical reference insertion in the typical case either. I honestly do not see how imagining a podium makes more sense than a simple `@name`.

Comment: Er, aren't the @name replies only removed in cases where it is absolutely, trivially unambiguous who's being addressed? I cannot fathom why this is such a contentious issue.

Comment: @camccann - Well.. can you tell by a mere glance, without going through the details, if the above comment by Jeff Atwood is adressed to everyone or someone particular?

Comment: @Saul: Irrelevant. He didn't use a reference, and if he had it would not have been removed, just as my (technically superfluous) reference to you was not removed from this comment.

Comment: @camccann: The point is that with automatical removal, there is no quick way of telling whether the reference was omitted intentionally or behind the scenes. A comment addressed to the public looks the same as the one addressed to the OP. Which, unlike before, requires one to waste time on counting participants and on reading an unreferenced comment to find out who is the actual recipient.

Comment: Who cares? *Everything* is addressed to the public. Even if a comment is "addressed to" the OP, if it's not adding useful content for everyone it's noise and probably shouldn't be there at all. Comments aren't even that important in the first place. They could remove the @name notifications entirely and little of value would be lost.

Comment: @camccann: Well, some of us apparently care. I am not arguing about importance of comments, they were deemed important enough to be implemented separately after the initial launch of SO. All I am saying is that explicit references reduce the effort of reading.

Comment: They were deemed possibly useful for reducing clutter in answers. Making it more difficult to engage in extended discussions in comments on non-Meta sites is a *good* thing. I can only assume that anyone seriously impacted by this change has been egregiously misusing comments.

Comment: @camccann: This is where I disagree. I have time and again obtained very useful tidbits from comments on SO. Moving them to a third place pretty much pulls the plug on their usefulness. Moveover, under the banner of "We don’t run Stack Overflow. The community does.", every user should at least have an uncontested right to voice their opinion about what constitutes a misuse and what doesn't.

Comment: I've contributed to closing in excess of 700 questions, so as a member of the community I'm very familiar with voicing my opinion about what constitutes misuse of the site. Adding superfluous nonsense with no informational content definitely qualifies.

Comment: @camccann: You wrote earlier something about comments not being important.. now all of a sudden it's 700. Anyhow, in my view, explicit references are a good thing because they create distinction. Whether others agree is a matter of debate as seen here and on a few other similar posts.

Comment: Ok. You're not even reading what I say anymore, are you? If you're not even attempting to participate in good faith, I give up.

Comment: @camccann: Of course I have good faith, by having a different opinion. You are repeating over and over again the same old mantra of noise. Whereas the other camp came up with 9 substantial arguments and a constructive proposal to mitigate some of the damage this change caused. How about debating those?