# Two @/ats, One comment... Change the message?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comment-replies, grammar

I just tried to @/at two people in one comment and I think the message reads rather weird:

[image]

I am notifying two people, but, this message just reads very weird to me. (Others think the same! I checked on Super User chat to make sure it isn't just me as I am not the best at Grammar!)

I think it should be changed to:

> "Only one user can be notified at a time. The post owner will
>   automatically be notified"

or, I think better

> "Only one user can be notified by you. The post owner will
>   automatically be notified"

What do you think?

Comment: If you really want clear wording: "*The post owner is always notified, even if you don't use @user.*"

Comment: Or: "*even if you don't use @the-actual-username-you're-trying-to-use*". That still wouldn't explain why you're blocked from writing the comment. It sure felt weird to see this message for the first time. @Robert

Comment: @Robert Harvey - I was working more on the first half... yeah, the second bit needs work as well!

Comment: I just assumed that people using @user know what that means.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that there's a quite-reasonable bias against lengthening the text of this notification message, but I think it would be somewhat clearer to say:

> Only one @user notification is allowed per comment.
>   (Remember that the post owner is always notified, so you don't need to use @user.)

That said, I'm not sure what you think is confusing or grammatically/stylistically strange about the way it is currently written. The `@user` notation seems to be one that is pretty universally understood, especially by people who are trying to use it in their comments.

Comment: Good point about people understanding @user... Personally, my problem is only really with the word "additional"... Just think it is weird. I hate to be one of "those" people correcting grammar, especially when my own isn't that good... but... when I saw this, I just thought "what!", and asked others who agreed - and as other people seem to suggest things on here, I thought "why not!"

Comment: @William: Oh, I see what you're objecting to now! It isn't "one additional" user, it's *one* user. The "additional" requires you to make the connection between the post owner being automatically notified and the `@user` syntax, which don't at all look the same to an outsider unfamiliar with implementation details. On second thought, I'm not sure how I missed that myself! I guess I was following the Meta discussion about it before I ever read the error message.

Answer (score 1):

The message isn't very clear, and others have proposed better texts. I'm wondering why not skip the message altogether and just send the notification to **all** the @users? I know it's status-by-design, but why not?

Comment: That's a totally different question. It's been discussed to the death on Meta already. Have you tried searching? Start reading [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation), then [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97283/dont-remove-the-part-of-my-comment).

Comment: @Cody your reading list has absolutely nothing to do with my answer, IMO. Have you tried reading my answer? For your convenience, I've put a bold font where it matters.