# Using @ to address a comment

Tags: support, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

I wanted to comment a question. There were already other comments.

I wanted to adress my comment to OP.

So I type `@the_op_name This is my comment` but the part `@the_op_name` was not shown ?

It's my last comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648977/apache2-and-php5-not-working)

What happened ?

Comment: Also see [Don't remove the @ part of my comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97283/dont-remove-the-part-of-my-comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment will appear in the OP's inbox even without the @the_op_name, so it was removed because it was unnecessary.

Post owners always get notifications for comments in their posts (questions and answers)