# Can't address this user in a comment

Tags: bug, comments

I just noticed some weird behaviour which I don't really understand. Maybe a bug, or is it just something I didn't get yet?

I'm refereing to this question: [Porting code from Unix using Visual Studio or MingW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992393/porting-code-from-unix-using-visual-studio-or-mingw/20993452?noredirect=1#comment31546320_20993452)

In the answer there is a comment from this [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147407/andrejs-cainikovs)

Now I wanted to ask something using the `@` to address him, but strangly his name doesn't appear in the selection box which usually appears. I entered part of the name manually, but when I submitted the comment, the name was removed from it and it appeared as if typed without it.

Comment: It's because nobody else is involved in the comments, so it will go to him (only) anyway.

Comment: Oh! I was confusing it with another user, otherwise I wouldn't have used the address anyway. OK, I didn't know that the addressing will dissapear in that case as I never had seen this before.

Comment: This is a stupid design decision by our SE overlords, but they stick their fingers in their ears and sing when we complain to them, so [STATUS-BY-INEPT-DESIGN](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97283/147191).

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen, don't see why this is stupuid. If there is only one poster involved, then it makes sense. Might be overkill to adress this special case but it doesn't hurt either.

Comment: It's stupid because it's confusing.

Answer (score 3):

As per [how-do-comment-replies-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) the author of a post will always be replied to.

> The first author of the question or answer will always be notified of
>   any new comment.

Additionally any @user comments that are known to be superfluous (only 1 other user in conversation who is the poster) will be automatically stripped out

> The first author of the question or answer will always be notified of
>   any new comment. There is no need to use @name to notify them. (You
>   may still use it for clarity, if needed; however if only you and the
>   author have been commenting on the post so far, the @name will be
>   [automatically removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation/97099#97099) from the beginning of the comment, as it adds no
>   value.)