# Why do comments longer that 15 characters have an error?

Tags: support, comments

Title says it. So this user posted a comment, and I replied. The message was longer that 15 characters long, but I still got the error saying it needs to be longed that 15 characters. How is this happening?

> [image: Error]

And why is this so?

Comment: This is a longer comment to @UniKitty What helps?

Comment: It probably doesn't count the @UniKitty when calculating the real length before submitting.

Comment: I don't understand why? @PythonMaster can put that, so why can't I?

Comment: What is the URL of the original question?

Comment: @DavidPostill [This](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224616/create-a-bat-file-to-run-cod-4-multiplayer/224638#224638) is it. But he changed it from UniKitty to Sajith so it doesn't make sense now

Comment: @David http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224616/create-a-bat-file-to-run-cod-4-multiplayer/224638#224638

Comment: What does @PythonMaster have to do with it?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ nidz smoother ones :D

Comment: @DavidPostill I think PythonMaster deleted his comment

Comment: @nicael install the script and do it :P

Comment: @DavidPostill http://stackapps.com/q/6353/26088

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because in [this case](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224616/create-a-bat-file-to-run-cod-4-multiplayer/224638#224638) @SwedishGamerz is the owner of the post you are commenting on, so the username is stripped. You get:

> What helps?

And it's shorter than 15 chars.

That's really quite annoying and [there's a request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97283/dont-remove-the-part-of-my-comment) not to remove `@OP` from the comments.

Comment: Wow. So simple these answers can be nowadays