# Please autocomplete @User2 even if you only notify @User1

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-replies, autocomplete

#### Background

I know that @replying to more than one user in a comment is not allowed as explained in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/348196). I've always hated that and thought that there are valid use-cases for mentioning two users in one comment but I also know that requests to remove this restriction have been shut down over the years<sup>*</sup>. **So, that's *not* what I'm requesting here**.

#### The problem

In a lot of situations, I need to type some user's name in a comment for reasons other than having them notified. For example:

> Hey @User1, please do X and also consider Y as per **User2**'s suggestion if you want Z.

Now, because I mentioned `@User1`, the autocomplete stops working for User2 even if preceded by an `@`. To type User2's name, I'm stuck with one of the following options:

- **Type it manually**
  Should be pretty simple. However, in many situations, it's not. Some usernames are long and complicated, possibly with non-ASCII characters, or the name is just not familiar and (if you don't like getting names wrong like me,) you have to be extra careful.
- **Copy and paste it**
  Again, simple in theory but one has to use the mouse and cannot even double click to select the name because it's a hyperlink.
- **Use a workaround**
  A workaround that I've been using is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> then <kbd>Del</kbd> to delete the first `@`, jump to <kbd>End</kbd> to type the second user's name, then back to the beginning to restore the `@`. Believe it or not, this is faster than the previous two options in many cases. Still not ideal though.

#### My suggestion

If you're not going to allow us to mention (@reply to) multiple users in one comment, can you at least enable autocomplete for the second (and above) `@`'s ***and*** automatically convert `@User2` to `User2` when the <kbd>Tab</kbd> button is pressed (so that the comment only contains one `@`)?

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>Surprisingly, I couldn't find any of those posts at the moment but I didn't do a lot of research anyway because it's not exactly relevant.</sub>

Comment: Sounds nice, I do have some hesitation that it might confuse people.... like when you use an @reply to the author of a post at the beginning of a comment, and it's automatically removed, this is something that could confuse newer users. "I put an @ in front of it, but now it's gone and if I add it again I get this error when I try to post my comment"...

Comment: @Tinkeringbell When the user tries again, they will get the same error message that is currently being used and it will explain to them that they can't use `@` with two users. They should then understand why it was removed (in case they didn't notice it at first). I really hope the restrictions around the `@` feature get lifted (including [the issue with removing `@author`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97283/348196) as you indicated) but unfortunately, such requests seem to always get shut down. Hence, why I posted this alternative request.

Comment: _@41686d6564_ If I do as you describe, I often use the format `_@username_` for the final rendering. It might be nice that the list appears for that 2nd or any mention if you type `_@`, and use that format for completion. What do you think? @tinker