# Started receiving notifications about new comments on the questions after moving comment into the chat

Tags: bug, comments, chat, moderator-tools

In [this question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1094700/15479) I've moved all comments into the chat. And now I'm receiving notifications about all new comments, even though I wasn't mentioned.

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

You're the only user (apart from the OP) who left a comment in the comment thread. Therefore, you get inbox notifications, as part of this feature request: 
[Micro-refinement to notifications for comments of others posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82134/295232)

Now, it would make sense that an auto-generated comment wouldn't cause these notifications. On the other hand, perhaps you do want to delete these new comments; the 'no extended discussion' policy holds for the OP as well.