# Place to list questions with any new activity where I've had activity

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make recent activity and responses show new comments on questions/answers I have commented on (even if I don't own them)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have)

There are often cases where a comment has been made against a question or an answer where I've posted a comment, or further answers have been posted after mine, and there is currently no way for me to be notified (unless the comment is @ me or against my answer, or it is an up/down vote on my answer). I'd love to have a place where I could go (or some filter I could manually set up) that would just show a list of all the questions (or the last 20, or 50, or whatever) where I have either commented, answered or edited, and there has been subsequent activity by any other user - ordered by the latest activity (any comment, any answer, etc). Each question would only have to be listed once, and the specific details of what activity drove it to the list (and who that activity belonged too) would not need to be included as it is under the current implementations of responses/activity.

Sure, I could favorite every single question I contribute to in any way, and go back and hit every single one when bored. But I think this could be made a little more consumable.

Comment: @slhck thanks, I searched but did not come across that question.