# new answer Notification can take a day or more

Tags: support, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [INSTANT notifications of answers to my questions - I’d love to have them and you?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6557/instant-notifications-of-answers-to-my-questions-id-love-to-have-them-and-you)

Is there a way to set notification to be received instantly? sometimes i have to wait more than 24 hours to get a notificaition.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6557/instant-notifications-of-answers-to-my-questions-id-love-to-have-them-and-you

Answer (score 2):

Why not come back to the site? It's faster and maybe you'll find something interesting while you're there. The notification system will probably remain unchanged.