# How to make Stack Overflow tell you about a new question with certain tag(s) the second it is asked?

Tags: support, tags, questions

For now, it's silly: I just keep pressing F5 button to have a chance of being the one who answers the new question first. I know about RSS but would subscribing to RSS mean that I get RSS updated instantly when a new question is asked? In my Firefox, RSS feeds are updated every 30 minutes and setting it to 1 min or less would be insane.

Comment: Of course, this will probably only exacerbate [the fastest gun in the west problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73/162705)...

Comment: Yeah, answering 30 minutes old question is insane.. by that time there will be like seven answers already with a big vote lead :-) Anyway, once you are in the West, you can't go without fast gun... :-)

Comment: Not an exact duplicate of these, but instant notifications have been asked about before: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6557/instant-e-mail-notifications-of-answers-to-questions and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60434/programmatically-sending-instant-e-mail-alerts-about-new-se-replies and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24659/instant-email-alerts-and-notifications and probably others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Firefox, I use the [ReloadEvery add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/reloadevery/) to set an automatic update time for the page to refresh, and set my Favorite Tags to the ones I want to see.

Answer (score 3):

Just a heads up, but the front page and (I believe) certain other common tag pages are cached aggressively... last time I heard it's only rebuilt every 90 seconds or so.

Answer (score 2):

I'm glad Lance's answer worked for you, but since this is Meta, here's the Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange answer to your question: the system does not support this feature.

Your only option is to use a third-party tool (or keep exercising that <kbd>F5</kbd> key).

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to [StackExchange alerts](https://stackexchange.com/filters/) for tags you want to follow which will email you new questions for a tag either ever 15 minutes, 3 hours or daily.