# Long site names get cut off in the Email Settings "+ more" sites tooltip

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, email, tooltips

Regarding: [Control the types of email you receive via our new Email Settings feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298906/control-the-types-of-email-you-receive-via-our-new-email-settings-feature)

First I would like to compliment the design and say that it looks really clean and user friendly.

One small bug...

When you hover over the "+ more" link to see the list of all the sites the settings affect, if the site name is long, like "Programming Puzzles & Code Golf", the name gets cut off in the tooltip:

[image: sites]

Comment: @aaronshekey it is a bit weird that an employee adds a status-completed tag but that the edit goes into the [suggested edit queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/53191) where I could potentially decline it, which almost happened as I assumed a bug or a bad joke. If you're not allowed your diamond here, at least get some rep ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've ended up removing this tooltip in favor of a link that lands you on a page that shows you all your communities. This tooltip wasn't very useful since we could only show 10 to maintain the layout. Since some users are in a *ton* of communities (awesome), we've killed it. Marking as resolved ✌️

Comment: Was this change rolled out yet, because I still see the tooltip?

Comment: It'll go out in the next build, sorry for not specifying.