# Documentation Beta and Stack Exchange icons are displaying in the Edit Email settings - Mobile web

Tags: bug, status-completed, email

In the [new Email Settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298906/) in mobile view there are two extra icons are displaying for my profile.

I have joined 22 communities in the Stack Exchange, but in the Edit Email Settings page I can see 24 site icons listed under **Your Communities** section.

**Stack Overflow Documentation Beta** and **Stack Exchange** icons are displaying extra.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Email settings]

Comment: Thanks, investigating and will likely fix tomorrow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the heads up, I've just pushed a fix for this to production.

Comment: The extra icons are not displaying now. Curious to know the actual issue, it's due to the extra fields from the API?

Comment: Meta sites and Stack Exchange are given a different `SiteType` in the database and we weren't filtering them out. We also weren't filtering out 'dead' sites (which Docs Beta is now classified as).