# What is the logic for the 4 sites chosen to be shown in Email Settings list of affected sites? Can it be changed to something more logical?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-deferred, email, preferences

In the [new email settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298906/control-the-types-of-email-you-receive-via-our-new-email-settings-feature?noredirect=1&lq=1), there are four sites shown for the list of sites that will be affected by the settings. The rest are hidden under the "+ more" link.

> [image: sites affected]

When looking at the four visible sites, I cannot figure out why these specific sites were chosen.

- The sites are not listed in alphabetical order.
- The sites are not my four top sites. If that would be the case, I would see the same order that I see on my [Network Profile accounts page](https://stackexchange.com/users/5924590/tot-zam?tab=accounts).
- This list is not showing the four sites that I visit most often.

Is this list based on site graduation date?
Is this list based on site popularity?

In the current state, the choice does not seem logical. I barely visit Super User or Area 51, and I would really rather see other sites instead of those.

Can the four sites chosen either be based on rep, like the Network Profile list is, or based on alpha order?

Comment: I can only assume that they are sorted by overall site activity or something like that

Comment: @NathanTuggy I never like when question titles wrap to a second line. I also don't know if "can we make it more obvious" makes sense. It is more "can we change it to something more logical".

Comment: @TotZam: "Obvious" and "logical" are largely synonymous here: something that is obvious to the user is either logical, or doesn't need to be. (I don't like two-line titles either, but I like titles that make no sense with their status-* tags even less.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid it's nothing more complex than the order of the site in our `Sites` table. The original sites (Stack Overflow = 1, Server Fault = 2, Super User = 3) are always the first few sites.

We *could* do something more fancy but it was deemed unnecessary for a v1 release. We'll probably do something like rep order when we ship v1.1, the date of which is yet to be decided.

Comment: So is this status-bydesign or status-planned, because I do think rep order would make the most sense?

Comment: Not sure yet, we haven't decided the most appropriate route; by rep may not even be feasible. I'll change it to [meta-tag:status-deferred] instead

Comment: Rep order would be consistent with the other graphic representations of a user's sites (i.e. flair), in addition to being consistent with the network profile.