# Tell me if I have any subscriptions form the new email management page

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, email, subscription

I've just gone to check my email settings based on the new feature described here: [Control the types of email you receive via our new Email Settings feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298906/control-the-types-of-email-you-receive-via-our-new-email-settings-feature?cb=1)

I noticed that I can manage my 'subscription' on that page, but I didn't think I had any. Clicking the link shows me I don't, but it feels like a better user journey if I don't have to click through to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the next release we plan to make the question subscriptions and newsletter management interface *a lot* better. It'll move into the user preferences screen instead of sending you off to stackexchange.com and will be similar in look and feel to the job alerts view.

We'll consider your suggestion when we get to implementing this. Thanks!