# Changing an email settings toggle scrolls the page horizontally to the left

Tags: bug, email

I was changing my email settings with the [new Email Settings feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298906) in a narrow browser window. I scrolled to the right to see the settings toggles. Whenever I change one of the toggles, the page scrolls to the left and I have to scroll to see the toggles again.

[image: GIF of the bug]

Comment: This happened for me too. I'm using Firefox 52.2.0 on Linux Debian 8.

Comment: For completeness' sake, I'm using Chrome 59 on macOS Sierra 10.12.6.